# Can't set Screen Resolution

Tags: 10.10, xorg, resolution

I'm having problems setting my correct monitor resolution as the correct one isn't available from Preferences -> Monitor.

I'm running a Geforce 440 MX, and there doesn't appear to be any correct driver for it. Jockey cannot find anything and the 96 driver doesn't work.

My correct resolution should be 1440*900.

Thank-you.

Comment: [nvidia-96](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/nvidia-96) should be what you need. What is the output of `dmesg | grep -i nvidia` and `grep -i nvidia /var/log/Xorg.0.log`?

Comment: nvidia-96 isn't compatible with 10.10 and if you install it, xorg wont load. The latter of those commands gives me the following: 
http://pastebin.ws/dpeb1e

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned above, the Nvidia-96 driver at present isn't compatible with 10.10. To fix this, however, I installed the driver (nvidia-96) and then did the following:

```
sudo su to become root
run nvidia-xconfig (this was in: /usr/lib/nvidia-96/bin/nvidia-xconfig)
go into /etc/X11/xorg.conf - I used vi
modify driver from nvidia to nv - in my case this was on line 94
save file
run startx
when ok - reboot machine - should go straight into your x-windows session
```

(See full post here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9955270&postcount=6 )

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that your screen simply isn't reporting that it handles that resolution.  You can add more modes to the list.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Adding%20undetected%20resolutions  Look farther along that page for instructions on how to make it permanent.

Comment: xrandr isnt working. Whenever I input it I get the following error: "xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default"