# How do you use an android tablet as a second display?

Tags: multiple-monitors, android

I've noticed people using a product for Windows and Mac called [iDisplay](http://www.shapeservices.com/en/products/details.php?product=idisplay&platform=none) which lets you use your Android or iPad as a secondary display. This seems like a great idea, and something that could be done on Ubuntu. Unfortunately, I've got no idea how to get started.

How could you re-create this setup on Ubuntu?

Comment: Similar question currently under discussion on the forums: [Use VNC as a second monitor](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1327186)

Comment: Same question on Super User: [Use VNC to create a second Screen](http://superuser.com/questions/305725/linux-use-vnc-to-create-a-second-screen)

Comment: Ok, the solutions presented here are network ones. But is there any chance to achieve this by simply faking a monitor through usb, to get the same experience as a monitor just like [Duet](http://techcrunch.com/video/duet-turns-your-ipad-into-a-mac-display/518566379/) does?

Comment: So Duet might be (essentially) emulating a DisplayLink chip in software -- I do not know but that's my guess. I wouldn't even try. What I would try (and it's not hard) is USB networking: tether (or reverse tether) your tablet and network away.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Get a VNC client for Android, start up a new VNC server session on your computer (don't just share the current display - use vnc4server not x11vnc), connect to it from the Android VNC client, and (the clever bit) share the PC keyboard and mouse between the two sessions using synergy.

All necessary software to do this is available in the standard repos for the Ubuntu side, and there's a few free VNC clients available for Android in the market.

You won't be able to drag windows across the displays using this method. For that I think you would need to use Xdmx to bond the two sessions. This is a lot harder and would probably cause you to lose 3D acceleration.

Also be aware that synergy and vnc don't use encryption by default so you need to tunnel the connections if you are not on a trusted network.

Comment: can add a example please

Comment: it'd be useful to have a step by step example that we can follow

Comment: How would this make a tablet a *second* screen - as in more screen space?

Comment: I had trouble with vncserver and Gnome 3. Every time I tried to launch vncserver the screen would go black. I ended up using tightvncserver (also in the Ubuntu repos) and it worked the first try with absolutely no configuration.

Comment: This is more of a KVM switch-like or a remote control solution than a second display. Yes, it gives you another set of input but output is the same on both devices - you can't even switch the tablet to a different virtual desktop than your main screen, switching on one switches both. It doesn't answer the question. Question is about using mobile devices for extra output space, not about input at all.

Comment: What do you mean by free? Free as in free speech or free as in free beer?

Answer (score 41):

Here's how to use Android as a second monitor, **share the mouse, drag windows between tablet and computer screens**.

The original source for the tutorial can be found [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=191555).

### A. Tutorial

#### Step 1. Create a new virtual monitor

My tablet's resolution is 1280x1024. (You may change `1280` and `1024` everywhere in the commands if your tablet is in different resolution. You may also need to change `LVDS1` if the default monitor's name is different).

Run in terminal:

1. $ `gtf 1280 1024 60`.

   There is a line in the output similar to `Modeline "1280x1024_60.00"  108.88  1280 1360 1496 1712  1024 1025 1028 1060  -HSync +Vsync`. Copy everything after the word `Modeline` (exclude it) into the next command.
2. `xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  108.88  1280 1360 1496 1712  1024 1025 1028 1060  -HSync +Vsync`

   (Note, in the next step, you may also need to change VIRTUAL1 with what you find in xrandr output as an output with new mode)
3. `xrandr --addmode VIRTUAL1 1280x1024_60.00`
4. `xrandr --output VIRTUAL1 --mode 1280x1024_60.00 --left-of LVDS1`

#### Step 2. Enable remote desktop for the virtual monitor

Start VNC:

1. `x11vnc -clip 1280x1024+0+0`

#### Step 3. Connect to the remote desktop

1. Get the tablet on the same local network as the computer. Either by connecting to the same Wi-Fi or by creating a hotspot with one device and then connecting with another to it (USB Tethering).
2. Find your computer's IP using `ifconfig` (when connecting from LAN).
3. Download a VNC app to the tablet and then connect to the computer using computer's IP (and selecting port `5900`) in the app.

#### Notices

- Credits: [kjans](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=191555), contents edited.
- **WARNING**: Data is unencrypted! (Relevant for Wi-Fi and not-LAN usage)
- **WARNING**: Devices from all the networks you are connected might reach port 5900 and therefore connect to your monitor! Being behind a router usually would limit it to be accessible only within your local network (If you're using USB connection, you could block local network altogether with `-listen <IP_ADDR>` option to `x11vnc` (where `<IP_ADDR>` is the USB network interface)).
- Running any of the 1 - 4 steps twice may output errors.
- After successful use, 5. step must be repeated for another connection.

### B. Script

The tutorial implemented as a script (Change the IP for use with the USB cable OR delete it and uncomment the line to use with Wi-Fi).

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
W=1280
H=800
O=VIRTUAL1
if [ "$1" == "create" ]; then
  gtf $W $H 60 | sed '3q;d' | sed 's/Modeline//g' | xargs xrandr --newmode
  # sed: get third line, delete 'Modeline', get first word, remove first and last characters
  gtf $W $H 60 | sed '3q;d' | sed 's/Modeline//g' | awk '{print $1;}' | sed 's/^.\(.*\).$/\1/' | xargs xrandr --addmode $O
  gtf $W $H 60 | sed '3q;d' | sed 's/Modeline//g' | awk '{print $1;}' | sed 's/^.\(.*\).$/\1/' | xargs xrandr --output $O --left-of LVDS1 --mode
elif [ "$1" == "on" ]; then
  x11vnc -listen 192.168.42.149 -clip ${W}x${H}+0+0
  # For use in Wi-Fi LAN.
  #x11vnc -clip ${W}x${H}+0+0 #**WARNING** Unencrypted stream. VNC accessible without password through port 5900 in all internet interfaces.
else
  echo "missing argument: [create | on]"
fi
```

Comment: @Prometheus, the `x11vnc -clip 1280x1024+0+0` can be replaced with `x11vnc -clip xinerama1`. Also, the `--left-of LVDS1` is not strictly necessary if you're latter going to use the `Monitors` settings app to position the extra monitor wherever you want.

Comment: `xrandr: cannot find output "VIRTUAL1"` was returned when I type in number 3. Any ideas?

Comment: `xrandr: cannot find output "VIRTUAL1"` returned from `xrandr --addmode VIRTUAL1 1280x800_60.00`

Comment: This works, except you must have an unused output capable of the target video mode for this to work. `VIRTUAL1` seems to be a placeholder for such an output, not something present in a typical system.

Comment: +1 For the idea of creating a virtual monitor

Comment: This solution lets you share the mouse cursor and drag windows between the virtual monitor (displayed on Android device via vnc) and the hardware one, correct?

Comment: @cprn Yes, you can share mouse cursor and drag windows. It's as if you had a second monitor connected

Comment: This should be accepted answer.

Comment: This deserves one more comment like "You may also need to change VIRTUAL1 with what you find in xrandr output as an output with new mode". I am still fighting, in my case a black vertical strip appeared on my primary monitor, overcasting my windows, but the new screen supposed to be "left-of" it... I'm gonna try again.

Comment: @Tooniis , I could add the VIRTUAL1  device following: https://github.com/brunodles/linux-second-screen/issues/4#issuecomment-420202393 . Also, you may have to change the name for the current device (in my case eDP1 instead of LVDS1). Last add: I added -viewonly when calling x11vnc in order not to let the tablet to use the cursor.

Comment: I got that error `xrandr: cannot find output "VIRTUAL1"`. Replacing VIRTUAL1 by HDMI-1 worked! (`xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 1280x1024_60.00`

Comment: Just a possible misunderstanding on my part: If I'm on a private wifi network (your average asus wifi router), would anyone still be able to connect through port 5900 from the outside, or would they need to be on the same wifi network? Also, why would I need to both restrict the ip (with -listen...) AND use usb, i.e. why doesn't the '-listen' command take care of the problem in all cases? (terribly new at vnc)

Comment: @Christopher.L It's should be accessible only from your local wifi network, then. Regarding the `-listen`, you're right, thank you for the note, I've updated the answer

Comment: add mode failing with nvidia propietary driver "xrandr --addmode DP-1 1920x1200_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  37
"

Comment: It works, but if you have gnome shell sometimes it crashes (lock) with the `xrandr --output ...` command. Instead, open Settings -> screen and enable the second screen from there.

Comment: How do I revert the `xrandr` second screen after I'm finished?

Comment: Also, is there a way to transmit audio as well with VNC? I didn't get audio even though I used `HDMI-2` in addmode.

Comment: how can i make the screen not slide? when i take my mouse beyond right edge, the whole screen starts to slide to left

Answer (score 20):

tl; dr: `xrandr --fb` and `x11vnc --clip` together make a killer combo.
More X11vnc opts: `-find`, `-clip`, `-display` ... `-opts`

The thread linked by *recognitium* has a really interesting idea, not sure whether he meant this one because I couldn't find the author he indicated and also because I followed up on the forum post there, I will post this separately and not as an edit:

1. First, let's assume: the primary machine does have a screen resolution of 1280x800, the secondary machine that you want to extend your desktop to over VNC has screen resolution of 1280x1024 and you want the extended screen to be right of your primary screen.
   The virtual screen needs to be `1280x800 + 1280x1024 = 2560x1024`. (extend it horizontally and make the vertical resolution the bigger of the two) So run `xrandr --fb 2560x1024`.
2. Now that the screen is bigger than your primary monitor, you have to make sure there is no panning or any other unwanted "feature" activated and also that the coordinates of your primary monitor's top left corner are 0x0.
3. `x11vnc -clip 1280x1024+1281+0` plus any other x11vnc options to taste :)

This should be it.

Comment: This seems like a way more seamless way to do it than the Synergy trick, nice! I'm curious how the extra virtual space will interact with my tiling window manager though. Will give this a shot in a little while and report back.

Comment: Defeat snatched from the jaws of victory.  The mouse pointer is not allowed to leave the primary screen.  :(

Comment: Seems interesting. I actually manage to have a double screen there, but unfortunately, the command `xrandr --fb 2560x1024` doesn't seem to have any effect. Which means I can't have a bigger screen than my primary monitor size ... :(

Comment: I read [further about this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19954/how-to-set-the-monitor-to-its-native-resolution-which-is-not-listed-in-the-resol?lq=1). Got a `X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  30
` error. My guess is that my laptop doesn't support higher resolution than native `1600*900`. Meaning this solution can't work. I'll have to find a double screen solution instead.

Comment: I finally made it work thanks to [this post](http://mikescodeoddities.blogspot.fr/2015/04/android-tablet-as-second-ubuntu-screen.html?showComment=1455126322826#c3505424202690276490) by running: `sudo xrandr --fb 2732x768 --output LVDS1 --panning 2732x768+0+0/2732x768+0+0` (I was missing the `--panning` option)

Answer (score 16):

1. Install `vnc4server` and `x2x`.
2. Then, set up a `.vnc/xstartup` config file. Mine looks like this

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   # Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
   unset SESSION_MANAGER
   unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
   # exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

   [ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
   [ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
   xsetroot -solid grey
   #vncconfig -iconic &
   #x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
   #x-window-manager &
   exec gnome-session
   ```

   It launches gnome-fallback desktop (I don't know how to make gnome 3 launch in vnc).
3. To launch vnc server, use `vnc4server -geometry 800x480` command. Of course, instead of 800x480 you have to set your tablet's resolution.
4. Launch `x2x -east -to :1`. That command says your computer to act as if display :1 had been to the right of the screen (use `-west` option if you want it to be on the left). You won't be able to move apps from one display to another, but you may use one mouse and one keyboard to control them both.
5. Connect to the display created with `vnc4server` from your tablet (the port number is 5900 + display number (e.g. for display :1 port number will be 5901) (display number is shown in the `vnc4server`'s output)).
6. To exit from `x2x`, press `Ctrl-C`. Alternatively, you may launch it in the background (`x2x -east -to :1 &`). Then you will first need to move it to foreground (`fg`), or kill it with `kill $!` (be cautious, it kills last process launched in background).
7. To remove the created display, call `vnc4server -kill :1`, where instead of `:1` you may set your new display's number.

Comment: Thanks for x2x... Why no one else mentions it on the entire internet ??? Saved me big time. Synergy requires cyanogenmod or similar on your tablet. Also no one mentions it.

Comment: I already know `x2x`, find this post by searching for *x2x android* on google... But +1 for `.vnc/xstartup`, especialy for `unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`!! Small but rich and very usefull post, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This is in principle possible using `xdmx` (distributed multihead X) which allows you to create a single desktop using two X-servers running on separate machines.

Three scenarios are possible in principle, but none are as seamless as iDisplay, because they all require restarting your X-session at least. I have not been able to get either to work perfectly, but I am running Ubuntu 10.10 and can't upgrade for various reasons.

The three are:

1. Run an X-server on Android (there are two available now in the app store) and use `xdmx` to combine with your desktop or laptop display. - didn't work for me because `xdmx` crashed when the pointer moved to the tablet part of the desktop.
2. Run a second X-server with vnc backend on your computer, use `xdmx` to combine that into one desktop with your computer screen, then look at the virtual part with a vnc viewer on the tablet - didn't work for me because `xdmx` requires all X-servers to have the same color visuals, which is not the case for the VNC server and the real display, and I wasn't able to convince `vncserver` to change.
3. Run two VNC servers, one for each screen, then connect them with `xdmx` and look at each part with a VNC Viewer on the respective machine. - This came closest to working for me, unfortunately input was messed up. it was also quite slow in true-color over Wi-Fi. I used this script to start `xdmx` and the two instances of `vncserver`:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh 
   vncserver :2 -geometry 1024x768 -depth 24 && \
   vncserver :3 -geometry 1920x1120 -depth 24 && \
   startx -- \
   /usr/bin/X11/Xdmx :1 \
   -input :2 \
   -display :2 \
   -display :3 \
   -ignorebadfontpaths \
   -norender \
   -noglxproxy \
   +xinerama \
   -nomulticursor
   vncserver -kill :2 
   vncserver -kill :3
   ```

YMMV

Answer (score 9):

Just wanted to add that if you want a better connection between your android device and your computer, you can use USB :

Be sure you have enabled USB debugging ( https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options )

Then install adb via `sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb`

Then if your VNC server is running on your computer on port 5900, use adb with :

> adb reverse tcp:5900 tcp:5900

That way your computer 5900 port will also be accessible on your android device through `localhost:5900` so configure your android VNC client to connect to `localhost:5900` instead of `your-computer-IP-addres:5900`

Comment: Essential to making this work without external connection

Answer (score 7):

I made a simple bash script to make a tablet a second display. Copy `ipad_monitor.sh` (Don't worry. it also works with Android) in my [blog post](https://kbumsik.io/using-ipad-as-a-2nd-monitor-on-linux).

What's different from the other post is that you can set position of the second screen with additional argument very easily.

Edit: I included the original `ipad_monitor.sh` here. run this command like:

- `./ipad_monitor.sh --right` or `./ipad_monitor.sh --left`
- `./ipad_monitor.sh --right --portrait`
- `./ipad_monitor.sh --right --portrait --hidpi`

The basic idea of this script is the same as others, running `xrandr` and `x11vnc` but I included options like which side you would like to attach the screen.

```
#!/bin/sh
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "THE BEER-WARE LICENSE" (Revision 42):
# <k.bumsik@gmail.com> wrote this file. As long as you retain this notice you
# can do whatever you want with this stuff. If we meet some day, and you think
# this stuff is worth it, you can buy me a beer in return. - Bumsik Kim
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Configuration
WIDTH=1024  # 1368 for iPad Pro
HEIGHT=768  # 1024 for iPad Pro
MODE_NAME="mode_ipad"       # Set whatever name you like, you may need to change
                            # this when you change resolution, or just reboot.
DIS_NAME="VIRTUAL1"         # Don't change it unless you know what it is
RANDR_POS="--right-of"      # Default position setting for xrandr command

# Parse arguments
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
  case $1 in
    -l|--left)      RANDR_POS="--left-of"  ;;
    -r|--right)     RANDR_POS="--right-of" ;;
    -a|--above)     RANDR_POS="--above"    ;;
    -b|--below)     RANDR_POS="--below"    ;;
    -p|--portrait)  TMP=$WIDTH; WIDTH=$HEIGHT; HEIGHT=$TMP
                    MODE_NAME="$MODE_NAME""_port"  ;;
    -h|--hidpi)     WIDTH=$(($WIDTH * 2)); HEIGHT=$(($HEIGHT * 2))
                    MODE_NAME="$MODE_NAME""_hidpi" ;;
    *) echo "'$1' cannot be a monitor position"; exit 1 ;;
  esac
  shift
done

# Detect primary display
PRIMARY_DISPLAY=$(xrandr | perl -ne 'print "$1" if /(\w*)\s*connected\s*primary/')

# Add display mode
RANDR_MODE=$(cvt "$WIDTH" "$HEIGHT" 60 | sed '2s/^.*Modeline\s*\".*\"//;2q;d')
xrandr --addmode $DIS_NAME $MODE_NAME 2>/dev/null
# If the mode doesn't exist then make mode and retry
if ! [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  xrandr --newmode $MODE_NAME $RANDR_MODE
  xrandr --addmode $DIS_NAME $MODE_NAME
fi

# Show display first
xrandr --output $DIS_NAME --mode $MODE_NAME
# Then move display
sleep 5 # A short delay is needed. Otherwise sometimes the below command is ignored.
xrandr --output $DIS_NAME $RANDR_POS $PRIMARY_DISPLAY

# Cleanup before exit
function finish {
  xrandr --output $DIS_NAME --off 
  xrandr --delmode $DIS_NAME $MODE_NAME
  echo "Second monitor disabled."
}

trap finish EXIT

# Get the display's position
CLIP_POS=$(xrandr | perl -ne 'print "$1" if /'$DIS_NAME'\s*connected\s*(\d*x\d*\+\d*\+\d*)/')
echo $CLIP_POS
# Share screen
x11vnc -multiptr -repeat -clip $CLIP_POS
# Possible alternative is x0vncserver but it does not show the mouse cursor.
#   x0vncserver -display :0 -geometry $DIS_NAME -overlaymode -passwordfile ~/.vnc/passwd
if ! [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo x11vnc failed, did you \'apt-get install x11vnc\'?
fi
```

Comment: Do you have a name for the script/app or any alternative link that you can post to help avoid link rot? Here we generally try to be as self contained as possible so as not to rely on other sites staying up, especially if those sites contain the bulk of the info that would be relevant to an answer where that info isn't actually put into the answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/827798)

Comment: @sbergeron I see. I include the original code here.

Comment: @anonymous2 You're right. I included the bash code here.

Comment: Ah, much better.  I think this should be able to stick around like this.

Comment: I _love_ the licence. Haven't tried the script yet, but will already buy you a beer for introducing the concept to me.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**:

```
    $ sudo apt-get install x11vnc
    $ WINDOW_ID=$(xwininfo | awk '/Window.id/{print $4}') && x11vnc -viewonly -nopw -avahi -id $WINDOW_ID >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Now, just click at the window you want to share.

---

**FULL**:

I have an iPad and Chromebook and I would like to use them as my monitors, to use some terminal commands `htop`, `iptstate`, `nmon`,etc . So, I'm lazy guy and made it using:

1. Package instalation: `sudo apt-get install x11vnc`
2. Open some terminal and put `xwininfo | awk '/Window.id/{print $4}'` and click in the window you want to share. The output will be something like:

   ```
    $ xwininfo | awk '/Window.id/{print $4}'
    0x4402f34
   ```
3. Now you can start your `x11vnc` session:

   ```
    $ x11vnc -viewonly -nopw -avahi -id 0x4402f34 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
   ```
4. Resize the window (0x4402f34) to have the best image as possible.

Mind the associated **port** of your **session**: `5900 -> :0`, `5901 -> :1`, `5902 -> :2`...

Works fine with X11 apps: Firefox, OpenOffice, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I use the xorg dummy  driver and x11vnc -clip.
The mouse point is not stuck on the edge.

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-dummy
```

There is the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` for dummy driver on second screen:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Configured Video Device"
    Driver "radeon"         #CHANGE THIS
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Default Screen"
        Monitor         "Configured Monitor"
        Device          "Configured Video Device"
EndSection


##Xdummy:##
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Videocard0"
  Driver "dummy"
  #VideoRam 4096000
  VideoRam 256000
EndSection

##Xdummy:##
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "Monitor0"
#  HorizSync   10.0 - 300.0
#  VertRefresh 10.0 - 200.0
#  DisplaySize 4335 1084
EndSection

##Xdummy:##
Section "Screen"
  Identifier "Screen0"
  Device "Videocard0"
  Monitor "Monitor0"
EndSection



Section "ServerLayout"
  Identifier   "dummy_layout"
  Screen       0 "Default Screen"
  Screen       1 "screen0" rightof "Default Screen"
    Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection
```

Then login to X session and run:

```
x11vnc -clip 1024x768+1280+0
```

Comment: Any way to do this without xorg.conf? If I create one on my computer then my graphics get completely messed up.

Comment: Is Xinerama still supported?  How about xrandr?

Answer (score 2):

These instructions are to create an "additional" screen for your linux machine using a tablet or any computer through a VNC client.

I made these steps in Mageia3 32Bit (have not tried 64bit) but should be similar for other distros as well (i.e. Ubuntu).

Make sure you have all the required packages with the following terminal command:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc autoconf automake x11-font-util libtool libxi-devel ibopenssl-devel libxfont1-devel libpam-devel x11-util-macros x11-xtrans-devel x11-server-xvfb x11-server-xdmx x11-server-devel x11-server-source
```

Once you have all the above packages, issue these commands:

```
cd /usr/share/x11-server-sources/
./autogen.sh
./configure --with-fontrootdir=/usr/share/fonts --with-xkb-path=/usr/share/X11/xkb --with-xkb-output=/usr/share/X11/xkb/compiled --enable-dmx
make
```

If you don't get any errors, patch Xdmx (simply put, it has been "broken" for some time):

open `/usr/share/x11-server-sources/hw/dmx/input/dmxevents.c`, and change line 730:
 change this:

```
POINTER_ABSOLUTE | POINTER_SCREEN, &mask);
```

to this:

```
POINTER_RELATIVE | POINTER_DESKTOP, &mask);
```

IF line 730 is different use this section to find correct line: 
Orginal section - line to change marked with *

```
    case ButtonPress:
    case ButtonRelease:
        detail = dmxGetButtonMapping(dmxLocal, detail);
        valuator_mask_zero(&mask);
        QueuePointerEvents(p, type, detail,
 *                         POINTER_RELATIVE | POINTER_DESKTOP, &mask);
        return;
```

Check your version of Xdmx by running `./configure --version` in `/usr/share/x11-server-source/`, for **Xdmx 1.13** and older you also have to make these changes (for 1.14 and newer you can skip to the "make" step below):

open `/usr/share/x11-server-sources/dix/getevents.c`, line 1395:
    change this:

```
if (flags & POINTER_SCREEN ) {    /* valuators are in screen coords */
```

To this:

```
if (flags & ( POINTER_SCREEN | POINTER_DESKTOP) ) {    /* valuators are in screen coords */
```

(Original section - line to change marked with *)

```
    /* valuators are in driver-native format (rel or abs) */

    if (flags & POINTER_ABSOLUTE) {
*       if (flags & POINTER_SCREEN ) {    /* valuators are in screen coords */
            sx = valuator_mask_get(&mask, 0);
            sy = valuator_mask_get(&mask, 1);
```

open `/usr/share/x11-server-sources/Xext/xtest.c`, line 311:
    change this:

```
flags = POINTER_ABSOLUTE | POINTER_SCREEN;
```

to this:

```
flags = POINTER_ABSOLUTE | POINTER_DESKTOP;
```

(original section - line to change marked with *)

```
       case MotionNotify:
            dev = PickPointer(client);
            valuators[0] = ev->u.keyButtonPointer.rootX;
            valuators[1] = ev->u.keyButtonPointer.rootY;
            numValuators = 2;
            firstValuator = 0;
            if (ev->u.u.detail == xFalse)
*               flags = POINTER_ABSOLUTE | POINTER_DESKTOP;
            break;
```

`/usr/share/x11-server-sources/include/input.h`, line 73:
Add this line after the line starting with `#define POINTER_EMULATED`:

```
#define POINTER_DESKTOP         (1 << 7)
```

After making the above changes, re-execute (in `/usr/share/x11-server-sources/`):

```
make
```

You should have a new Xdmx file in `/usr/share/x11-server-sources/hw/dmx/`. We need to install that globally for ease, so I recommend renaming your existing one:

```
sudo mv /bin/Xdmx /bin/Xdmx-old
```

and copy the new one in place of it:

```
cp /usr/share/x11-server-sources/hw/dmx/Xdmx /bin
```

Now you're ready to do your first trial, the following commands allow you to keep your main/existing display (`:0`) running and open a new display with the multi-monitor support.
I am using icewm with these commands to make it a little more lightweight (I use KDE on my main display `:0` and open any large-multi-monitor application in the new multi-head display).
You can most definitely script these commands for ease of use (it's what I did) -- Any of these commands can be executed on console and/or terminal window of any display, the only requirement is that they are executed in order.

This command creates your new display as a frame buffer for your VNC display `:2` (adjust screen size as desired):

```
Xvfb :2 +xinerama -screen 0 1024x1280x24 -ac &
```

This starts a new lightweight X session on your physical display as display `:1` (there are different ways to do this):

```
startx 'icewm' -- :1
```

This command starts the multi-display between your physical screen and the virtual screen and starts icewm for window manager:

```
Xdmx :3 +xinerama -display :1 -display :2 -norender -noglxproxy -ac & DISPLAY=:3 starticewm
```

Now open a terminal window and start the vnc server (change password as desired):

```
x11vnc -display :3 -passwd test -clip xinerama1 -noshm -forever -nowireframe &
```

The only thing left to do now is to fire up your VNC client and connect to your VNC -- **you may need to disable or add an exception to your firewall** to port 5900 so you can connect to it.
Another thing to keep in mind is that some VNC clients don't display the remote cursor position, I certify that "Mocha VNC" for iOS works great if you turn off the option "local mouse".

Enjoy dragging windows between your main monitor and your new virtual second monitor (while also being able to use the tablet to click/type on things in the second monitor).

To close Xdmx press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> twice.

Automation:

I use this bash script to start the whole process (also kills Xvfb on exit):

```
Xvfb :2 +xinerama -screen 0 1024x1280x24 -ac &
xinit dual -- :1
ps | grep Xvfb | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill
```

Then I have a custom `~/.xinitrc` file with this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ~/.xinitrc
#
# Executed by startx (run your window manager from here)

if [[ $1 == "" ]]
then
  exec startkde 
elif [[ $1 == "xterm" ]]
then
  exec xterm
elif [[ $1 == "dual" ]]
then
  exec Xdmx :3 +xinerama -display :1 -display :2 -norender -noglxproxy -ac & DISPLAY=:3 starticewm & x11vnc -display :3 -passwd test -clip xinerama1 -noshm -forever -nowireframe
else
  exec $1
fi
```

Troubleshooting:

- When running Xdmx if you get an error saying `sh: /usr/local/bin/xkbcomp: No such file or directory` you may need to do execute: `cd /usr/local/bin" and "ln -s /bin/xkbcomp`, then try Xdmx again.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F7</kbd> is supposed to work in Xdmx to switch to other consoles/xsessions but for some reason it doesn't work, what I do is simply execute `sudo chvt X` (where X is a console/xsession number) to switch to my main display. Also when you switch back to Xdmx you may get some drawing issues on any open windows, I just click on the taskbar to hide/show the window again forcing a redraw.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still wondering on this topic: the xrandr and x11vnc clip does work; to enable the mouse to get over there you need to use the panning argument to set the mouse tracking area:

```
xrandr --fb 2560x1024 --output LVDS1 --panning 1280x1024+0+0/2560x1024+0+0
```

Then when running xvnc use:

```
x11vnc -clip 1280x1024+1281+0 -nocursorshape -nocursorpos
```

That stops VNC from attempting to use it's own cursor tracking and paints the cursor as part of the screen image.

I made notes here http://mikescodeoddities.blogspot.ae/2015/04/android-tablet-as-second-ubuntu-screen.html

Answer (score 2):

Use [vnc_virtual_display_linker](https://github.com/mrenrich84/vnc_virtual_display_linker)

The tool sets up a second virtual monitor for connecting with VNC as described in many of the previous answers. It even supports connections from Android devices using a USB cable.

Answer (score 2):

Since none of the solutions above worked for me on Ubuntu, I'll share the script and steps I use.

1. Get a "Headless Display Adapter";
   Xorg dummy package didn't work for me. Maybe because of NVIDIA, and there was no clear solution to be had after 3 hours. So, got myself one of these dummy HDMI devices online. Look up "dummy HDMI".

[image: dummy hdmi]

2. Install a VNC app on android;
   I am using "bVNC Free" app, which works well and simple.
3. Get the cables;
   If you have Type-C ports on both devices, get a cable to connect the ports.
4. Enable developer mode in android device;
5. Install x11 and adb packages needed on the Ubuntu device;

```
     sudo apt update
     sudo apt install android-tools-adb x11-xserver-utils x11vnc
```

6. Setup VNC app on android;
   Use `127.0.0.1` for VNC connection settings IP and port `5901`. All else as default.
7. Get the dummy HDMI's display name using `xrandr`; One display should be the main display and other the dummy. Mine was "HDMI-A-0";

```
xrandr | grep ' connected'
```

8. Run the script below to start;
   It must be run on terminal. It can be saved in an executable `.sh` file to make it easy to start every time.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    
    #Set screen resolution and display name
    resh=1920;
    resv=1080;
    dummy="HDMI-A-0";
    
    #Define mode and mode resolutions
    mode=$(cvt $resh $resv | grep "Modeline" | xargs | sed 's/Modeline //' | sed 's/\.00//');
    moderes=$(echo $mode | awk '{print $1;}');
    
    #Reset and kill all existing processes
    adb kill-server
    xrandr --output $dummy --off
    xrandr --delmode $dummy $moderes
    xrandr --rmmode $moderes
    killall -9 x11vnc
    
    #Start adb, set xrandr and start x11vnc
    adb reverse tcp:5901 tcp:5901 &
    sleep 5
    adb shell monkey -p com.iiordanov.freebVNC -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1 &
    sleep 5
    xrandr --newmode $mode
    xrandr --addmode $dummy $moderes 
    xrandr --output $dummy --mode $moderes
    x11vnc -bg -clip "${resh}x${resv}+0+0" -rfbport 5901 2>/dev/null 1>&2

    #Notify and exit
    echo "VNC ready; Open VNC app to use. This window closes in 10 seconds.";
    notify-send "VNC ready";
    sleep 10
    exit;
```

9. Once ready, open the VNC app and open the saved connection. It should show the second display. Using Ubuntu's display manager, the position of the second display can be slightly altered. More room for experiments.

**Updated script (Jan'24)**

Here is my updated script to replace step 8 and 9, and run the script in background using root cronjob.

8.a. Save the following script in `$HOME/startvnc.sh`, or any other preferred location. Update the "*Custom Definitions*" section with your inputs.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Custom Definitions (Screen resolutions, display names, modes, etc..)
user="username"; # Run whoami command on terminal to get username
origresh=1280; # Current PC display resolution horizontal
dummyresh=1280; # Dummy device resolution horizontal
dummyresv=800; # Dummy device resolution vertical
dummyname="HDMI-A-0"; # Run xrandr | grep ' connected' to get main display
defscreentout=15000; # ~15 seconds; Default screen timeout on phone;

#Standard Definitions
mode=$(cvt $dummyresh $dummyresv | grep "Modeline" | xargs | sed 's/Modeline //' | sed 's/\.00//');
moderes=$(echo $mode | awk '{print $1;}');
vncappid="com.iiordanov.freebVNC";

#Setup xrandr
if [[ $(xrandr -q | grep $moderes | wc -l) -eq 0 ]]; then
    xrandr --newmode $mode
    xrandr --addmode $dummyname $moderes 
    xrandr --output $dummyname --mode $moderes
fi

#Function: To notify as root
function notify {
    if [[ -z "$1" || -z "$2" ]]; then
        echo "Valid format: notify user title comment(optional)";
        return -1;
    fi
    local userid=$(id -u $1);
    if [[ ! -z "$3" ]]; then
        sudo -u "$1" DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$userid/bus notify-send "$2" "$3";
    else
        sudo -u "$1" DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$userid/bus notify-send "$2";
    fi
    adb shell cmd notification post --style bigtext --bigtext "$2" "1" "1";
    return;
}

#Function: To start adb and x11vnc
function startService {
    adb reverse tcp:5901 tcp:5901 &
    sleep 1
    adb shell monkey -p $vncappid -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1 &
    sleep 1
    adb shell settings put system screen_off_timeout 2147483647
    x11vnc -noxdamage -nobell -wait 0 -defer 0 -ping 1 -nonap -sb 0 -speeds 6,100000,1 -repeat -bg -clip "${dummyresh}x${dummyresv}+${origresh}+0" -rfbport 5901 2>/dev/null 1>&2
    sleep 3;
    notify "$user" "VNC-client-ready" "Open VNC app on device to view";
    sleep 5;
    return;
}

#Function: To stop and exit
#Close the vnc app on phone before unplugging cable, so that the following commands can reset defaults.
function stopService {
    # Reset pref
    adb shell settings put system screen_off_timeout $defscreentout;
    
    # Reset and kill all existing processes
    adb kill-server
    killall -9 x11vnc
    
    # Notify and return
    sleep 2;
    notify "$user" "VNC-client-stopped" "Unplug the cable now";
    sleep 5;
    return;
}

#Loop and run
while /bin/true; do
    if [[ $(adb get-state) == "device" && $(adb shell "dumpsys activity | grep top-activity" | grep "$vncappid" | wc -l) -ne 0 && $(ps aux | grep -P 'x11vnc([\S\s\w]+)5901$' | wc -l) -eq 0 ]]; then
        startService;
    fi
    if [[ ( $(adb get-state) != "device" || $(adb shell "dumpsys activity | grep top-activity" | grep "$vncappid" | wc -l) -eq 0 ) && $(ps aux | grep -P 'x11vnc([\S\s\w]+)5901$' | wc -l) -ne 0 ]]; then
        stopService;
    fi
    sleep 3;
done;

exit;
```

8.b. Backup crontab and add a root cron job (reboot) for the above script. Reboot to activate script, or just run the command directly on terminal the first time. Replace "*username*" (`whoami`).

```
sudo cp "/etc/crontab" "/etc/crontab.bak"
sudo echo "@reboot username bash $HOME/startvnc.sh >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &" >> /etc/crontab
```

9. Insert the dummy HDMI plug, connect device with PC, unlock screen lock, and use the device like any other HDMI display. However, remember to close the app first before unplugging, to reset defaults (such as screen timeout delay..) on the device.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the tutorial guys, i'll share what worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04

Get [AndroidVNC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=android.androidVNC&hl=fr) here for your tablet

Get x11vnc for your Ubuntu pc by running

```
sudo apt-get install x11vnc
```

I had to use the Xorg dummy driver method.
Here's what my /etc/X11/xorg.conf file look like :

```
Section "ServerLayout"
Identifier     "X.org Configured"
Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
**Screen        1  "Screen1" rightof "Screen0"**
InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
**Option         "Xinerama" "1"**
EndSection

Section "Files"
ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
Identifier  "Keyboard0"
Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
Identifier  "Mouse0"
Driver      "mouse"
Option      "Protocol" "auto"
Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier   "Monitor0"
VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
ModelName    "Monitor Model"
DisplaySize 1680 1050
EndSection

**Section "Monitor"
Identifier "Monitor1"
VendorName "Dummy"
ModelName "Dummy"
DisplaySize 2704 1050
EndSection**

Section "Device"
    ### Available Driver options are:-
    ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
    ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
    ### <percent>: "<f>%"
    ### [arg]: arg optional
    #Option     "NoAccel"               # [<bool>]
    #Option     "SWcursor"              # [<bool>]
    #Option     "EnablePageFlip"        # [<bool>]
    #Option     "ColorTiling"           # [<bool>]
    #Option     "ColorTiling2D"         # [<bool>]
    #Option     "RenderAccel"           # [<bool>]
    #Option     "SubPixelOrder"         # [<str>]
    #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
    #Option     "EXAVSync"              # [<bool>]
    #Option     "EXAPixmaps"            # [<bool>]
    #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
    #Option     "EnablePageFlip"        # [<bool>]
    #Option     "SwapbuffersWait"       # [<bool>]
Identifier  "Card0"
Driver      "radeon"
BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

**Section "Device"
  Identifier "Dummy"
  Driver "dummy"
EndSection**

Section "Screen"
Identifier "Screen0"
Device     "Card0"
Monitor    "Monitor0"
SubSection "Display"
    Viewport   0 0
    Depth     1
EndSubSection
SubSection "Display"
    Viewport   0 0
    Depth     4
EndSubSection
SubSection "Display"
    Viewport   0 0
    Depth     8
EndSubSection
SubSection "Display"
    Viewport   0 0
    Depth     15
EndSubSection
SubSection "Display"
    Viewport   0 0
    Depth     16
EndSubSection
SubSection "Display"
    Viewport   0 0
    Depth     24
EndSubSection
EndSection

**Section "Screen"
Identifier "Screen1"
Device "Dummy"
Monitor "Monitor1
EndSection**
```

You probably wont need everything in there, just run X -configure to get your system autoconfig and add the dummy sections (stuff between the asterisks) to your file. Resolution for dummy screen in xorg.conf should be your main monitor width + your tablet resolution width, in my case 1680+1024=2704 keep your main monitor height, 1050 in my case.Restart X server/Reboot/Pull power plug, whatever suits you more :).

Run x11vnc by doing

```
x11vnc -rfbauth ~/.vnc/passwd -clip 1024x550+1680+0
```

Here the resolution should be your tablet width x tablet height + Main display width + 0

Connect to your Pc using the androidVNC client, make sure to enable localmouse option. That should be it, now feel the weirdness of having linux run over android :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of issues with the other techniques listed here. I wish I had a better solution, but my slow and simple solution is a good starting place.

For the VNC server, I tried the `vncserver` package but the screen would go black and I'd have to restart `gdm` to get anything working again. I switched to `tightvncserver` and it worked the first time with no configuration.

To share the mouse/keyboard between screens I used [x2vnc](http://fredrik.hubbe.net/x2vnc.html). This could also be used with [win2vnc](http://fredrik.hubbe.net/win2vnc.html) to share the mouse/keyboard with a Windows PC next to your Linux PC.

**Final commands:**

```
sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
tightvncserver
sudo apt-get install x2vnc
x2vnc -east localhost:1
```

At this point you should be able to open the second screen in a VNC program by connecting to `YOUR_IP_ADDRESS:1`. To start a program on the VNC screen, open a terminal, set `DISPLAY`, and then run the command. For example, to open `xterm` on the VNC "screen", run:

```
export DISPLAY=:1
xterm
```

Using this approach the second screen is pretty slow. Still, a lot of the other options I tried ran into dead ends, and this one worked with no configuration at all.