# Can I use my Android tablet as a 2nd monitor in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: android, external-monitor, tablet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you use an android tablet as a second display?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28608/how-do-you-use-an-android-tablet-as-a-second-display)

I love Ubuntu 12.04, but would like to use my Samsung Thrive 10.1 in Android Tablet as a second monitor.

Is this possible?