# Can I connect my Ubuntu Desktop to Google Cardboard?

Tags: android, bluetooth

This might be a strange question, but I am wondering if I could use [Google Cardboard](http://www.google.com/get/cardboard/) to replace my monitor.

For this I'd like to connect an Ubuntu-Desktop with an Android Smartphone through Bluetooth (or alternatively USB).

Does anybody know how I could accomplish that?

Comment: Mabey something along the lines of using VNC on the phone to link to the Ubuntu box, but it would just be VNC attached to your head. not a poor mans-VR.

Comment: Thanks Scott, but VNC, may be too much. I just want to get the desktop displayed on the smartphone. Mouse and keyboard shall still be directly connected to the Desktop.

Comment: You could still use those.

Comment: Okay, thanks, so I will start to try that out. So http://askubuntu.com/questions/28608/how-do-you-use-an-android-tablet-as-a-second-display might describe a solution?

Comment: I've never tried to use VNC as a second display, simply a mirror of the first,headless one.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I finally got the vnc solution working. Interesting. But the problem with it are network latency and size of smartphone display, because I don't get the full desktop sreen shown.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a VNC app for Google Cardboard that you could try. It comes in a free version with ads and a paid version, but if you're up for it you could build it yourself since it's open source.

- app: [Cardboard VNC Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.chai.cardboardremotedesktop.lite)
- source code: [CardboardRemoteDesktop](https://github.com/svenhenrik/CardboardRemoteDesktop)

To get the most out of it I recommend using a lower resolution (or large fonts) on your VNC server. I prefer using a wireless keyboard/mouse connected to the server, but you can also control the pointer with the headset/trigger and use a bluetooth keyboard.

Comment: I know that this is incredibly old, but I just want to say that I fully appreciate this business model. I think the world would be a better place with more open collaboration and fewer people separately working on the same types of projects. That's a waste of time. But, providing someone with a ready-to-go version is still a good way to make profit off of your efforts.

Anyways, thank you :)

Answer (score -2):

Trinus Gyre seems to work if you have wine and .NET 40 installed. A bit of lag though, hard to play games with.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.loxai.trinus.test&hl=en