# xrandr "cannot find mode" although mode is added and shows on xrandr

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, xrandr

I'm trying to use my tablet as an extended monitor for my laptop, following Prometheus's answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28608/how-do-you-use-an-android-tablet-as-a-second-display).

I got to the point where I'm supposed to output the mode with VGA-0, but xrandr "cannot find mode."

```
$ gtf 1280 1024 60
    # 1280x1024 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 63.60 kHz; pclk: 108.88 MHz
  Modeline "1280x1024_60.00"  108.88  1280 1360 1496 1712  1024 1025 1028 1060  -HSync +Vsync
$ xrandr newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  108.88  1280 1360 1496 1712  1024 1025 1028 1060  -HSync +Vsync
$ xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1280x1024_60.00
```

At this point, prompting `$ xrandr` returns

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-0 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1280x1024_60.00 (0x2a6)  108.9MHz
        h: width  1280 start 1360 end 1496 total 1712 skew    0 clock   63.6KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1060           clock   60.0Hz
```

So there is a mode called `1280x1024_60.00`. But now, trying to output that mode, I get

```
$ xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1280x1024_60.00
xrandr: cannot find mode 1280x1024_60.00
```

Which I don't understand because it looks like `mode 1280x1024_60.00` has been successfully added.

Any advice or comment is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `newmode`, 1280x1024_60.00 is enclosed in double quotes, whereas on `addmode` and `output` it isn't.  Use double quotes on those two commands too.  At least, this is the correct syntax.  An additional problem is that you are trying to add a mode to a disconnected port "`VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)`" which won't work.  The port has to be connected first.

Judging from what the post says, you're probably using an incorrect port though.  Your VGA-0 port is for connecting an actual monitor through a 15-pin VGA connector.

Comment: Gotcha. I guess I'll have to use another way. Thanks!