# Mirror Ubuntu screen on phone

Tags: 17.04, screencast

I was wondering if there was a way to mirror my Ubuntu screen to my android OS phone. I know how to mirror phone to PC, but could not find anything about the other way around. I would also want it to be wireless. Thank you!

I have Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: You can use tools like Teamviewer or similar. Other than that, not possible, and I'm afraid this isn't exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: This is more a question for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, NoMachine has an Android client: https://www.nomachine.com/getting-started-with-nomachine-for-android . I did not try the Android Client, but from PC to PC it's working fine.

Comment: NoMachine looks promising. I might test it myself.

Answer (score 0):

[Teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com)! You can see and control what is in your PC from your phone.

(This solution was already in your comments by  @MichaelBay)

Comment: Some attribution would have been nice, as well as a thought out answer instead this one liner that's even shorter and less informative than my previous comment.

Comment: sorry @MichaelBay I didnt see your comment. Do you think I need to change the answer?

Answer (score 0):

### [Jitsi Meet](https://meet.jit.si/)

You can share the desktop screen to your mobile phone just by both entering the same meeting of Jitsi Meet, which is an open-source web app.

1. Go to [meet.jit.si](https://meet.jit.si/) and use a random name or type your own.
2. The other device should enter the same meeting/virtual room.
3. On desktop share your screen (left-down corner).

Also, a [classic VNC connection](https://askubuntu.com/q/28608/349837) should work too.