# Screen mirror Linux screen on an android device?

Tags: android, ubuntu-for-android

I would like to see what's going on my Linux desktop screen on my android phone. When I'm away from my laptop.
I mean reverse of screen mirroring android device on a Linux desktop.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/942117/27968 is a similar question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you use an android tablet as a second display?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28608/how-do-you-use-an-android-tablet-as-a-second-display)

Answer (score -3):

Teamviewer does the job well and unlike many other vnc (virtual network computing) software it is pretty easy to set and go.

https://www.teamviewer.com/en/

Comment: Remote access != screen mirroring