# Can't Delete Outputs from Xrandr

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, xrandr, tablet

I was trying to use my android tablet as a second monitor as shown here: 
[Using an Android Tablet as Second Monitor via VNC.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28608/how-do-you-use-an-android-tablet-as-a-second-display)
Then, I made some mistakes while solving the problem. The mistakes which I did: 
- Created more than one output, in the section below you can see it,

> VIRTUAL1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>      1368x768_60.00  60.00
>
> VIRTUAL2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>     1280x800_60.00 (0x22b) 83.460MHz -HSync +VSync
>           h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock  49.68KHz
>           v: height  800 start  801 end  804 total  828           clock  60.00Hz
>
> mode_ipad (0x241) 63.500MHz -HSync +VSync
>           h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1176 total 1328 skew    0 clock  47.82KHz
>           v: height  768 start  771 end  775 total  798           clock  59.92Hz

I created these three virtual monitors by mistakes but, only **VIRTUAL1** output shows up in the System Settings --> Displays.

Even I tried to close it with:

```
xrandr --output VIRTUAL1 --off
```

It still shows up itself on the displays section.

Can you help me deleting these virtual monitors? 
For any help, thanks in advance...