# Is it possible to start an additional X server after the system boots in 12.04?

Tags: boot, xorg

I'd like to have 2 VT's running, one on VT7 with the standard lightdm + unity interface and another on VT8 running a custom script which will launch a virtual machine in full screen.

At the moment I've tried writing an `init.d` script with no luck and I can't find any details on a configuration file which will allow me to start 2 servers.

I suppose my ideal answer would be one which points me to a config file I can edit to start up an additional server.

Edit - I forgot to mention in the text that **I already know how to start another X session: I'd like this to start automatically at boot**.

Comment: `startx -- :n` will start another X server on VTn.

Comment: Actually that doesn't, it starts a display with number n. To start on VTn, you need to run startx -- :1 VTn

Comment: The classic answer is to modify a line in `/etc/ttys` but this file appears to have been supplanted in non-ancient versions of Ubuntu (by `/etc/console-setup`). Maybe an equivalent would be to edit `/etc/init/tty6.conf` and add your X incantation? I don't have time to explore this and provide a detailed answer.

Comment: @AlexHirzel Not tried it yet but from memory that's what I'm looking for. I'll give it a shot in a moment.

Comment: Any word on this? Just curious because I have become interested in the same setup!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I do it for games.

```
xinit session -- :1 -xf86config config.conf
```

Where *session* should be replaced by the session you'd like to start in the new Xorg display, and *config.conf* is the configuration file.

For starting it automatically, take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/74711/18953).

Comment: I've already tried the rc.d method with no luck :/

Comment: @jackweirdy Doesn't it work when you put the script in `/etc/init.d/`? Don't forget to make it executable.

Comment: Tried that before. The main X instance wouldn't start and my PC kept rebooting. I'll paste the script in a bit, but it worked fine when executed post-login.

Comment: @jackweirdy Does this work? http://askubuntu.com/questions/74189/run-a-startup-script-with-lightdm

Comment: That solved it, thanks :D If you could change your answer to include a link to that it'll probably help anyone who comes to view this question at a later date :D

Comment: This sounds cool. What is the benefit of doing it for games?

Comment: @isomorphismes Not sure whether there's still massive advantages nowadays but back then it helped because there was no resource-intensive composited desktop environment being processed on the same Xorg instance as the game was running on.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about a config file that you can edit, but I do know how to start another X server. Assuming **n** is the TTY number that you want to start the X server on, the command is

```
startx -display :2 -- :2 vtn &
```

You will then get a small white terminal window on that TTY that you can move your mouse in. From there, you need to run the command to start a window manager (e.g. **gnome-session**) from that TTY.

Comment: I've discovered this much so far, the problem is I'd like to *automate* it, IE have it start up by default as opposed to running a script each time

Comment: unrecognized option vtn, what is vtn?