# Running a shell script automatically

Tags: scripts

Could any one please suggest me on which boot level or /etc/rc.x folder should I include my shell script so that it runs automatically immediately after login or just before the system prompts for login in LTS 12.04

Thanks

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up

Comment: Look at this this [Run a startup script with lightdm](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74189/run-a-startup-script-with-lightdm) or [Script to run when starting a user session](http://askubuntu.com/a/123758/265974) for a script after login use this [Where are the startup scripts for Unity Desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/a/462395/265974)

Answer (score 0):

You may have it to run at runlevel 3, according to this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel#Ubuntu.

I guess you can be sure to do the right thing not creating these links by yourself, but by using ad-hoc, standard programs. The usual command-line one is update-rc.d. Its manual page in section 8 of the manual is rich of details.

Comment: actually running at runlevel 2 is working. As the documentation says for the ubuntu in the given link if i am running the script in third level the system is not making any attempts to run it.

Comment: Sorry about that, it was a typo!

Answer (score 0):

After login with your user add your script in `~/.bashrc` file to run your script whenever the user login.
Give execute permission on file.

```
sudo chmod +x script.sh
```

If you want to add these script for all user copy your script in `/etc/profile.d/` directory.