# Run a command at startup with LightDM

Tags: lightdm

I'm using LightDM as a greeter.

I need to perform a command before the login screen. I've put a file called `rotate.conf` inside the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` folder. That file contains a command to rotate the second monitor (it is the only way to have it works properly).

I've tried different rows of code but it seems it doesn't read that instruction.

```
[SeatDefaults]
command=xrandr --output DP-0 --rotate left
```

I've tried even without the `[...]` and `command=` but without success.

I've also added the last line in `user.conf`

```
[UserList]
minimum-uid=500
hidden-users=nobody nobody4 noaccess
hidden-shells=/bin/false /usr/sbin/nologin /sbin/nologin
greeter-setup-script=/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy that file into `/etc/init/lightdm` not `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` folder.

Hopefully, this could solve your problem:

- [Run a startup script with lightdm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74189/run-a-startup-script-with-lightdm?rq=1)