# Screen resolution startup script in LightDM

Tags: resolution, lightdm, xrandr

I used to fix the resolution of my screens (Which occur quite often, we have 5 computers having this problem at office and one at home) by setting and adding mode with xrandr in the gdm start script.

This tip was given here
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

But this time in 12.10 I am unable to find any file like that /etc/gdm/Init/Default.
Does anyone know if there is still one startup script at the launch of LightDM graphic session ?

Tks

Comment: I found how to do it using ~/.xprofile but the draw back is the login screen does not have the new resolution nor the UBUNTU startup logo (This last is for sure not a big problem only it would make better feeling for windows users coming to see our beautiful Linux machines...)  It also need to be done for all sessions.

Comment: see this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent