# Is there a way to disable laptop LCD on startup when external monitor is connected

Tags: 12.04, gnome, display, external-monitor, xrandr

Am running 12.04 and Gnome Shell with a Thinkpad X201 laptop and docking station. When I start the Thinkpad in the docking station with the lid closed, Ubuntu is recognizes that the external monitor is primary (DP1), but defaults the laptop LCD (LVDS1) as on. I would like it to be off at startup when in this mode.

I discovered this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/69501/2692) and developed a version of the script indicated:

```
XRANDRexternal="xrandr --output HDMI1 --off --output LVDS1 --off --output DP1 --mode 2560x1600 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output VGA1 --off"
XRANDRnoexternal="xrandr --output HDMI1 --off --output LVDS1 --mode 1280x800 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output DP1 --off --output VGA1 --off"
if xrandr | grep -q ' connected'
then
${XRANDRexternal}
else
${XRANDRnoexternal}
fi
```

I then tried to place this in my lightdm.conf as suggested in the post:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
display-setup-script=/usr/share/display-setup-script.sh
```

I verified that the script worked by running it first in terminal. At this point I can't automate this at startup. I tried both the display-setup-script and session-setup option and neither work. I also tried sticking this into my startup applications to no avail.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this further.

Answer (score 2):

After hacking away at it, I finally got it to work.. I was never able to get this to execute from LightDM but adding the sleep option and adding it to startup applications worked

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 5
XRANDRexternal="xrandr --output HDMI1 --off --output LVDS1 --off --output DP1 --mode 2560x1600 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output VGA1 --off"
XRANDRnoexternal="xrandr --output HDMI1 --off --output LVDS1 --mode 1280x800 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output DP1 --off --output VGA1 --off"
if xrandr | grep -q ' connected'
then
${XRANDRexternal}
else
${XRANDRnoexternal}
fi
```