# Automatically move Xubuntu panel to external monitor

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, xfce, panel

I am using xubuntu 13.04 with a dualmonitor setup. (external monitor as primary, laptop als secondary) I am using `xandr` to makeup my monitorsetup. However I recognized that the xubuntu panel on the top by default will always be placed on the laptop monitor. I know that i can move the panel via the panel preferences. This works. But i want to somehow either let it move automatically to the right monitor (the primary one) or to move it with a terminal command (so i can create a script which takes care of moving the panel to the primary monitor)...

any ideas?

Comment: Please post your xrandr call. The `--primary` call might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [How can I make xrandr customization permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent)
There are several ways to do that. First write a arandr script, second have the script start after login.
Follow the thread, there are more than 1 solution. The last one seems easy enough.

Cheers.