# Keep dual monitor position settings

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xrandr

I can change the position of my dual monitors using `arandr`.  However, I have to do this every time I log back in.  I'd like to keep the configuration settings without having to do this every time.

I didn't have a `.config/monitors.xml` initially.  I tried adding it with the correct settings, but it still doesn't work.

I've also tried looking at other answers like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent), but I don't have any of the files he's referring to including `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` which seems to be the functional one.

Is there anything I can do to keep these settings or have my machine respect `.config/monitors.xml`?

I've also tried updating `.profile` to include the `xrandr` calls, but these will only run when I open the terminal -- not that I could get them to work properly anyway.

I've also tried changing this via `nvidia-settings` and clicking "Save to X configuration settings," but the settings still do not persist after relog/reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it! Just 'System Settings' => 'Displays' and set from there :)