# VGA output for Old pc

Tags: resolution, acer, xrandr, vga, tv

I have a acer 5710g, i had some problems about heating and i turned it into a media system just for downloading stuff and watching movies by removing internal screen. However i have some problems about it. It wasn't able to use it in any 16:9 resolutions, 1024x768 was maximum, Than i found a way to deal with it which is called "xrandr" (you would probably know what that is) However it keeps returning backwards whenever i turn on/off system. I had to do all stuff all over again. Any ideas to keep it like that forever??

Comment: What commands are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to try ArandR, which is a front-end for xrandr. Once you get the screen set up the way you like it, you can "save" the parameters to a shell script (.sh) file. You can then make the script execute at startup. http://www.ubuntugeek.com/arandr-a-simple-visual-front-end-for-xrandr.html

You can also look for autorandr (https://github.com/wertarbyte/autorandr). I use this to detect that my laptop lid is closed and use an external display.

Comment: i wasn't able to launch that one (arandr), i have installed it but it says a system error occurred, what can i do?

Comment: Not sure I can help you troubleshoot ArandR. ArandR is just a GUI, and you don't necessarily need it to do what you want to accomplish.

For example, I execute the following to change to 2560 x 1600 resolution using my display port adapter... Something like this could be executed at start up in the Startup Programs control panel with whatever parameters you need.

xrandr --output VIRTUAL1 --off --output DP3 --off --output DP2 --mode 2560x1600 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output DP1 --off --output HDMI3 --off --output HDMI2 --off --output HDMI1 --off --output LVDS1 --off --output VGA1 --off

Comment: This thread may be helpful to you too:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent