# xrandr not saving settings permanetly in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ati, graphics, resolution, screen, xrandr

I just installed Ubuntu.  I am new to Linux, so I will need this explained in pretty basic terms please.  I have two monitors.  I use a AMD R7 2xx graphics card.  I haven't installed the AMD drivers but don't know if I need to or not.  In terminal I used the command `xrandr --addmode DVI-0 1600x900` to add that resolution to my second monitor.  It works fine until I restart the computer.  I read something about needing to change a xorg file in `/etc/X11`, but that directory doesn't exist on my computer.  Not sure what to do.

Comment: You either have to set and save your settings with a graphical tool or run xrandr at login. http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/use-xrandr-to-set-a-screen-resolution/

Comment: @bodhi.zazen fancy ! you even got a blog :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make xrandr customization permanent?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd add your command `xrandr --addmode DVI-0 1600x900` to list of Startup Applications, or create a `.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart` , so that the command runs on every login.

Comment: Note that the command might (and probably will) break if it runs before the desktop is fully loaded. Especially if a second monitor is attached.

Comment: I would, but would that mean I would still get the error window each time I log on.  It says: "Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors.  Then it says below that could not assign CRTCs to outputs: and a really long list.

Comment: @JacobVlijm never had this issue, I've a `.desktop ` file which configures my dual screen with 15.04.

Comment: I assure you, in many cases it does, as a result of `xrandr` to break in that case.

Comment: It worked, however, I am still getting this annoying error message when I reboot.  It is a long list of CRTC errors.  It doesn't seem to affect anything, but it is rather annoying

Comment: Try lightdm.conf too.

Comment: @Andrew can't help you with that error, but when you login , try running in terminal xprop and clicking on that error popup  or whatever. At least it will tell you what program runs it

Answer (score 2):

You can add

```
display-setup-script=<your_xrandr_command>
```

to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` in `[seat defaults]` section.

This will ensure it starts before you login into the system.

It also can be done in xorg.conf file, or better in a new file in

`/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/<50-some_name.conf>`

Comment: I will try this now.

Comment: It mast be AFTER `[seat defaults]`, I was wrong before.

Comment: Hi Pilot6, I guess that is `/usr/share...` , correct?

Comment: It is correct..