# How can I implement a new resolution mode using xrandr consistently?

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

Firstly, I have connected a new 1280 x 1024 (1080p) monitor at optimum resolution to my Toshiba Satellite laptop via VGA. I run Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

The problem is that the default resolutions available for the secondary display are only 1024x768 and 800x600.

The fix I have used is:

```
xrandr
```

to determine all visual outputs, and then

```
cvt 1280 1024
```

which gave me `"1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync`

I then used

```
xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
```

and then

```
xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1280x1024_60.00"
```

This gave me a selectable resolution of 1280x1024 in the system settings for the secondary display, which is fantastic and works a treat, but I am really struggling on implementing a fix for the resolution to be available permanently.

The fixes offered are to add a script using a .xprofile; xrandr start up scripts  in kdm/ gdm; and setting xorg.conf which were found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Setting_xrandr_changes_persistently).

I have not been successful in any of these three, possibly because I have not understood them. I cannot find /etc/gdm; the only folder I can find in /etc similar is /etc/gdb. I also cannot find /etc/X11/xorg.conf to be able to implement a change there either. 
As with .xprofile, I cant seem to make a .xprofile file in /home as I get the message "you do not have permissions to save the file".

My question basically is, how can I add the custom resolution I have made using xrandr as a permanent fix for my secondary screen as described in the guide and overcome the problems listed above!

Thank you very much if you are able to help. Please let me know if you require any further info.

one last thing - if i am able to make a .xprofile file, where should it be correctly saved?

I cannot find /etc/gdm; the only folder I can find in /etc similar is /etc/gdb. I also cannot find /etc/X11/xorg.conf to be able to implement a change there either. 
As with .xprofile, I cant seem to make a .xprofile file in /home as I get the message "you do not have permissions to save the file".

Thank you.

Comment: Add it to `xorg.conf`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make xrandr customization permanent?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent)

Comment: If the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` is too much complicated, see in the above link the second answer about the use of startup scripts in `lightdm`. Surely much easier, as you already have the commands to run to make it work. So, you only need to add your two xrandr commands in a script and configure the lightdm.conf file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have found /etc/lightdm but there is no lightdm.conf file, only users.conf  in that directory and that file has limited info in it

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue.

I managed to create a .xprofile file and saved it to the home directory. I then added

```
xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1280x1024_60.00"
```

The only trouble I had was permissions with saving a .xprofile which somehow was not an issue when I did it a second time around.

This works fine now and the new resolution is applied onto the secondary screen every time.