# How can I run this script at startup / change setting

Tags: nvidia, xorg, nvidia-settings

OK, how can i run this:

```
xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 144
```

on startup?

**OR:**

Make nvidia-settings remember that I've set it to 144Hz and not 60Hz

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 355.06  (buildd@lgw01-22)  Mon Aug  3 21:32:29 UTC 2015

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
# generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Philips PHL 272G5"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 160.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 146.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 650"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "1920x1080_144 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent

Comment: I have GDM; so this doesn't work. (I think)

Comment: what about /etc/gdm/Init/Default?

Comment: That file made no sense what-so-ever

Comment: Add that line as one of the commands to Startup Applications

Comment: Does Not work see answear below

Answer (score 0):

See the post here: [wiki.ubuntu - xrandr](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Setting_xrandr_changes_persistently), this shows you several ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start nvidia-settings as root:

`sudo nvidia-settings`

Go to `X Server Display Configuration`

change the rate to 144 and click on `Save to X Configuration File`

Now it should be permanent.

How ever if you want to start your script, when you log on, then you could use ~/xinitrc to run your script.

If you don't want it, then you can use

`system Menu > Preferences > Startup Applications`

if you copy your script to ~/bin (because ~/bin is included in your $PATH environment), then you can enter the name, otherwise you must enter the full path.

Comment: I deleted my xorg.conf file and made a blank one. Then I did that Save to X Configuration File thing but not as root, but then a password promp appeared. Did I do this right?

Comment: Yes, but never delete config files, always back up them with 
mv configname configname_backup.

If you have created the xorg.conf file, then open it
nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf

And search for Section Screen

you should have the following option:
    Option         "metamodes" "1920x1080_144 +0+0"

Comment: The nvidia thingy didn't work; moving on to next thing...

Comment: The startup Applications thingy doesn't work nether?

Comment: Can you post your xorg.conf file?
Did you gave your script executable rights?
chmod +x scriptName

Comment: Xorg.conf added to question

Comment: That's pretty strange, your xorg.conf file seem to be right. Did you reboot? You need to restart X to apply your changes

Comment: yes I've rebooted

Comment: Also gonna mention; I've had this problem earlier before I reinstalled ubuntu.

Comment: How do I save the script?

Comment: Which script, which editor you used to create it?

Comment: Startup Applications (Gnome 3.16?)

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login

Comment: I've done that, but it doesn't work.