# Can't add Custom Resolution

Tags: display, xrandr, display-resolution

```
sudo cvt 1920 1080 60
```

Declare New Resolution

Part of the output should be similar to this:

```
"Modeline "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync" (w/o the quotes)
sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Determine Name of Display

```
sudo xrandr -q
```

Add New Resolution Mode to Display Device

```
sudo xrandr --addmode Virtual1 1920x1080_60.00
```

I tried this but can't find this resolution in SYSTEM SETTING - DISPLAY. Please help me to how add a custom resolution in my system.
Thanks

Comment: Please use the [formatting tools](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to make your question more legible.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed out a step - so enter your above commands as well as (note that you don't need to use `sudo` for the `cvt` command):

```
xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
```

You will now have a resolution applied, but it won't be selectable from the `Display` window and is only temporary. To make the resolution visible in the `Display` window, follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/63855/146980) answer.

If you choose not to do that, then you make the resolution permanent but not visible in `Display`:

- Create a bash script, `xrandr.sh` for example, and place your xrandr commands into it:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
  sudo xrandr --addmode Virtual1 1920x1080_60.00
  xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
  ```
- Make the script executable with `chmod +x xrandr.sh`
- Search for "Startup Applications" in the dash, run it, and add the script as a startup application.

The commands will now run every time you log into your account.

**OR** you can go the easy way and use a program that does the above for you -  [ResolutionX.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/resolutionx)