# Multi-Screens Issue

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

Greeting all, just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS my PC use a intel graphic display with two monitors. But I can't detect the second monitor.

xrander output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

xrandr output with two monitors:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3200 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected 1280x1024+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024     75.02* 
VGA1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Any advise?

Comment: open a terminal and type the command `xrandr`.  Edit your answer to include the output of this command.

Comment: Done, I update the xrandr information

Comment: Based on xrandr I see only one monitor and that's plugged into the VGA port.  How is the 2nd monitor connected?

Comment: Correct and the VGA port is showing the other screen connect through DVI port.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see a DVI port listed in the xrandr output.  On my system it's listed as DVI-0.  Are you sure that your card supports this output?  It appears that your card has DisplayPort, HDMI, and VGA outputs.

Comment: It's working in Windows 7 & 10.

Comment: When I'm trying: xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1024x768 --same-as VGA1 it's duplicate the screen to both monitors. is there any way to split it?

Comment: I think there is a graphical way in Ubuntu. Check the Systems Setting items.   I use Lubuntu, so I have to use a command like `xrandr --output VGA-0 --left-of DVI-0 --primary`.  This moves the image on VGA to the left of the DVI image and sets it as the primary monitor.

Comment: Cool, it's working if I'm doing the following:

xrandr --addmode HDMI1 1280x800
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1280x800 --right-to VGA1

Is there any automatclly way on doing this? I do not want to do it everytime I'm rebooting

Comment: I made a script that runs when I log in.  That's pretty easy to do in Lubuntu, I think you can add it to the Startup Items in Ubuntu.  How about I post the results of this conversation as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `xrandr` output you posted, it looks like your card or driver does not support the DVI output.  Try using one of the other outputs, and make a simple `xrandr` script to configure your monitors at login.

My login script is just one line like this:

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --left-of DVI-0 --primary
```

I called it lxde-setup.sh and added it to the startup actions.

Comment: Is there any way I can setup a different resolution to each screen?

Comment: xrandr can do a lot of things.  there is a --newmode and --addmode options that lets you add resolutions that aren't listed in xrandr.  You can use the cmd `cvt [width] [height] [hz]` to create the data you need.  Not every resolution is possible on every card. See this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution and this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent/63855

Comment: And, if this information helps you, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey check mark!

Comment: Is there any way to give each screen a diffrent resolution?

Comment: I managed to see now in both screen but I'm stuck on the part of the resultion. I've looked on the link you sent and It didn't helped me.

Comment: I might be able to suggest something if you run `xrandr` again with both monitors working and paste the output into your question.

Comment: I've added it to the orignial post.

Comment: What you added does not show anything connected to the HDMI port.

Comment: You are correct, but still I can't work with two monitors. 
This is very strange...