# xrandr configuration don't persist

Tags: 20.04, screen

I used the following comand to set the positions of screens:

> xrandr --output LVDS-1 --left-of HDMI-1

But when I press Super + P and I change for one screen and I return to dual screen extended, the configuration is lost changing the LVDS-1 to righ side and I have to set again. Is there some way to keep this configuration?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent