# Input signal out of range after logging in KDE

Tags: monitor

I installed KUbuntu (Ubuntu with KDE) a few weeks ago. Yesterday, I used Synaptic to download and install the GL-117 game. When I ran it, my monitor went black and displayed this message:

```
Input signal out of range
Change settings to 1600 x 900
```

When the game starts and waits for me to make selections from the menu or change options, it shows a simulation of the game, while playing music and game sounds. I could hear the music and sounds, so the game was running.

But, I couldn't do anything. My monitor would not let me change settings. Not being able to use my monitor, I couldn't interact with my computer.  I finally forced a reboot.

The boot went normally up to and including the point where I enter my user password. After I entered my password, a black screen with the KDE Plasma logo appeared, which is normal. But, a few seconds later, my monitor again went black screen, with the "Input signal out of range" message. This continues to happen.

I'm able to use my computer by pressing the "Esc" key during boot. This allows me to use recovery mode boot. Recovery mode forces 1024 x 768 resolution, with 76 Hz refresh rate.

What could have GL-117 done to have caused this?

But, much more importantly, what do I need to do to fix this, so I can use my computer with the resolution I am used to?

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-65-generic
OS Type: 64-bit

HP S2031 monitor
NVIDEA Quadro 600 graphics card
Monitor connected to graphics card DVI port.
```

Others have had a similar problem. But, in the other cases, the problem occurred earlier during boot. In my case, the problem occurs later, after I enter my password. So, editing GRUB files won't help me.

I haven't been able to use solutions that involved using tools such as xrandr, since recovery mode makes it look like my system has only one possible video setting.

Comment: It seems clear that the game set your system's resolution to an invalid value. It is not clear to me why that would persist through a reboot, but I have never used Kubuntu. I have not run into this exact problem so I am posting a suggestion as a comment rather than an answer.  Since you can boot to a low resolution desktop, do that, create a script with an xrandr command to set your desired resolution, and set that script to autostart at login. Then reboot.

Comment: See answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/69501/243321 Not sure it's totally applicable to Kubuntu but the approach is what I'm suggesting.

Comment: Thanks. A lot of the potential solutions I found are years old, and often involve changing files that don't exist on my computer. The suggestion to set the mode using xrandr might have worked, but I found a way to fix the problem before I was able to try that.

Answer (score 1):

It's Fixed!

It looks like it was a bad refresh rate.

I found four files in ~.local/share/kscreen/ (Two were in that directory, and two in ~.local/share/kscreen/outputs.)

The contents looked something like this:

```
{
    "id": "<redacted>",
    "metadata": {
        "fullname": "xrandr-HP S2031-3CQ2210QR9",
        "name": "DVI-I-1"
    },
    "mode": {
        "refresh": 60,
        "size": {
            "height": 900,
            "width": 1600
        }
    },
    "rotation": 1,
    "scale": 1
}
```

Except the number following "refresh" in two of them was 120.  I used a text editor to change it to 60.