# Geforce(410m with CUDA) screen resolution on Ubuntu 12.04 issue

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, vaio, sony

I made a succesful installation of Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit on my Sony Vaio PCG-71811M. I have a Geforce 410M with CUDA,it seems works fine and i have already installed packages `nvidia-current` and `nvidia-settings` at version 302.17 (I think it's the latest in this moment), but my maximum screen resolution is 1366x768(and in the native display settings it's the same thing). How can I switch it to an highest resolution, like 1920x1080?

Comment: Please, check this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19954/how-to-set-the-monitor-to-its-native-resolution-which-is-not-listed-in-the-resol

Answer (score 1):

You can't force it to accept any higher resolution. I have the same laptop and the maximum resolution is exactly 1366x768. Everything works properly.