# How to set the monitor to its native resolution when xrandr approach isn't working?

Tags: 12.04, resolution, monitor, xrandr

I am trying to setup my Samsung syncmaster B2030 monitor in ubuntu 12.04. It's native resolution is 1600x900 which I am not getting in ubuntu and which I am trying to get.

I tried using xrandr approach provided in these urls: 
1) http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-change-display-resolution-settings-using-xrandr.html
2) [How to set the monitor to its native resolution which is not listed in the resolutions list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19954/how-to-set-the-monitor-to-its-native-resolution-which-is-not-listed-in-the-resol)

S1) 
I used

```
cvt 1600 900 60
```

to get the modeline. Output was:

```
# 1600x900 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.44M9) hsync: 55.99 kHz; pclk: 118.25 MHz
Modeline "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
```

S2) I then used

```
xrandr
```

and output was:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1152 x 864, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 connected 1152x864+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
1024x768       60.0 +
1360x768       60.0     59.8  
1152x864       60.0* 
800x600        72.2     60.3     56.2  
680x384       119.9    119.6  
640x480        59.9  
512x384       120.0  
400x300       144.4  
320x240       120.1  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

which gave me "VGA-0".

S3) Then I used

```
xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
```

But instead of adding the modeline it just threw an error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  29
```

**My system details:**

1) ubuntu 12.04 LTS

2) Graphic card: GeForce 9400 GT/PCIe/SSE2 (driver is successfully installed. I am checking it in System Settings > Details. And it's showing that driver is installed and its "GeForce 9400 GT/PCIe/SSE2")

3) Monitor: Samsung syncmaster B2030

4) Resolutions I am getting:

```
800x600
1024x768
1152x864 (I am currently using this one)
1360x768 (this one isn't working properly)
```

Does anyone know what I can do?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE (1):**

Today I tried it again. And adding a modeline (using --newmode) worked. But when I used --addmode by:

```
xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1600x900_60.00
```

It gave this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  30
```

Answer (score 1):

BadName means it interprets the .00 as special characters.  Simply change the name of the new mode by removing the decimal and everything after but appending a single letter or maybe try VGA.  Note there are double quotes around the newmode name, but not when adding it to a specific output nor setting the mode of the monitor.

```
$ cp off your xorg.conf file just in case.
$ xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60VGA"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --verbose --addmode VGA-0 1600x900_60VGA
$ xrandr --verbose --output VGA-0 --mode 1600x900_60VGA
```