# Problem with resolution after update ATI driver!

Tags: installation, ati, resolution

After installing the amd-driver-installer-12.6-legacy-x86.x86_64.run on my Ubuntu 12.10 laptop, my maximum resolution is 1024x768.

My GPU is ATI Radeon x1200 is integrated in my motherboard. I can see the up toolbar and the left toolbar with the 1024x768 resolution. And the compiz can't run.

Comment: Try the 'xrandr' commands listed [in this askubuntu question][1].


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/176812/how-to-set-the-monitor-to-its-native-resolution-when-xrandr-approach-isnt-worki

Comment: When I type the command 'xrandr', I get it "Can't open display"!

Comment: I'm not running 12.10 (am on 12.04 LTS), but if you hit the super key (i.e. the Windows key if you a Windows keyboard as most of us have) and then type 'Drivers', you will get to the drivers menu. Can you roll back to the previous driver, or is it the case that you installed amd-driver-installer-12.6-legacy-x86.x86_64.run because your graphics card isn't supported by 12.10 out of the box?

Comment: Thanks for your response guys, I did as you said nothing is appear in my screen!

Comment: Why did you install amd-driver-installer-12.6-legacy-x86.x86_64.run ? Can you hit the Super key then type Settings, then click the Displays button? Can you get to a terminal by using the CTRL+ALT+F1 combination? You can get back to the GUI desktop by using the CTRL+ALT+F7 combination.

Comment: I thought that amd-driver-installer-12.6-legacy-x86.x86_64.run it was the appropriate driver for my gpu! And I was wrong! When I press the Super Key and then type "Settings" and press Enter, nothing happens! Yes, I can get to terminal by using the CTRL+ALT+F1 and get back to the GUI desktop by using the CTRL+ALT+F7. This is my desktop! [link](http://i.imgur.com/xK3spwa.jpg)

Comment: Please give the URL where you got amd-driver-installer-12.6-legacy-x86.x86_64.run from. Are there any instructions there on removing it?

Comment: I unistall the driver follow the instructions from here [link](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx). And now the unity is not working!

Comment: Quickest way to fix this, I suggest, is back up any important data you have and reinstall the operating system. If you really need an alternate driver then suggest you ask here on askubuntu first in another question, stating what issues you're having and asking for advice on which driver to install, rather than installing random drivers off random websites :-)

Comment: Ok thanks for the advise but, after removing the Driver, my operating system working fine! I think is not needed to reinstall the operating system! I check an option in the Appearance Settings for the Unity and is fine now!

Comment: Well done! You should insert your last comment as an answer and mark as accepted so that others having a similar issue will have the way forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the wrong driver is follow the instructions from here (link)[http://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu] under the Title "After installing drivers from ATI binary"! Thanks for your help!