# Lower resolution with DVI and NVIDIA driver than with VGA

Tags: nvidia, graphics, resolution, monitor, dvi

First my setting:

**Machine:**

```
  Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-36-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 8 21:44:52 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Graphic Card: I have an old Quadro NVIDIA card**

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation NV18GL [Quadro NVS 280 SD] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0190
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 248, IRQ 16
    Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e8000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at f7000000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [44] AGP version 3.0
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidia_96, nouveau, nvidiafb
```

**cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version shows me:**

```
NVRM version: NVIDIA Linux x86_64 Kernel Module  96.43.23  Sat Sep  1 03:31:32 PDT 2012
GCC version:  gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
```

**My problem now is:**

I have a modern 27" monitor, and when I connect it with my graphic card with a VGA cable I can choose the native 1920x1080 resolution in the NVIDIA settings.

If I connect the monitor with a DVI cable, I only got 1280x960 as highest possible resolution.

How can I use the native resolution of 1920x1080 of my monitor with the DVI cable?
(The DVI cable is not the issue, I tried two other ones, same problem)

Thx in advance!

Comment: Maybe this helps: [How set my monitor resolution?](http://askubuntu.com/a/189364/23878)

Comment: Also you could give the nouveau driver a try. See [Feature Matrix](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/FeatureMatrix) of the [NV10 family](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/CodeNames#NV10)