# Unable to change resolution back to normal

Tags: resolution, display

After fixing the "System runs in low graphic mode"-error, the resolution of my screen changed to 640x480. Obviously, this is not my native resolution.

I cannot set it to the native resolution (1366 x 768) for some reason, since there is no other resolution shown in the Monitor Settings. Arandr also does not show 1366x768 as a possible resolution.

My laptop is a Samsung R519 with standard resolution 1366x768, with an Intel graphic card.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve my problem? I hope I explained it clear enough (if there is some missing info, please let me know)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm running Lubuntu (Ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 0):

This helped me, just for anyone who has the same problem: [How set my monitor resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189246/how-set-my-monitor-resolution)

The first answer, from BuZZ-dEE did the job.