# Wrong resolution - cant change

Tags: 14.04, unity, nvidia, display, display-resolution

I'm not new to Linux, but I newly installed it on this PC. Its been as smooth as always, but I have a problem with the display. It runs in 1024x768 on a 1920x1080 monitor, which is not exactly fun. In the "Display" dropdown, it says "1024x768" and "800x600". Also, its recognizing my VGA screen as "Built-In" which is not correct.

I have done searching and have not found an answer. However, most of these answers tell me to change my "xorg.conf". I don't have that file. And I also got an error called `Cant get gamma for native screen` or something like that when trying to add something with `xrandr`.

How can I make the resolution correct?

Comment: I had this same issue and solved it just by running 'Update Manager' once, then rebooting.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you could try the proprietary nvidia drivers and see if the system corrects itself.
I highly recommend to try this first, except of course if you got beef with non open source software running on your install.

Anyway, if you still want the nouvau drivers (hoping i spelled that right :P) or the nvidia drivers fail to fix your problem you can forcibly add your resolution (never ever mess around with the Xorg.conf files - seriously it can hang your system) with xrandr

```
cvt 1920 1080
```

this will tell you what option/arguments you should use for the next command
ie:`cvt 1024 600`
output:`# 1024x600 59.85 Hz (CVT) hsync: 37.35 kHz; pclk: 49.00 MHz
Modeline "1024x600_60.00"   49.00  1024 1072 1168 1312  600 603 613 624 -hsync +vsync`

so for the next command you should copy everything for the 'Modeline' and after:

`xrandr --newmode "1024x600_60.00"   49.00  1024 1072 1168 1312  600 603 613 624 -hsync +vsync`

then you must add the new resolution to your output (run xrandr to find your output name ie:VGA1)

```
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1024x600_60.00
```

finally to change to your newly added resolution run: `xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1024x600_60.00`

PS: some or all the commands listed may require admin rights (super-cow) so before all that just run `sudo su` to log as root

source (and more detail):https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr#Adding_undetected_resolutions

Comment: I told you, I've tried it! I get "Could not get screen gamma" or whatever it says. And my screen is recognized as "Built-In" so I dont know the name for it.

Comment: Oh, and I tried downloading Nvidia's binary blob. My system crashed and I had to reinstall. http://i58.tinypic.com/34njqzo.png

Comment: your name is 'Screen 0'

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't work for the parameters. Its in two words.

Comment: yeah i know hence the "'" in the 'Screen 0'

Comment: It doesn't work. Look at my picture:

Comment: http://i62.tinypic.com/2ztc3sk.png

Comment: i know this sounds strange but can you remove temporarily remove the package xserver-xorg-video-ati

Comment: Also to generate a Xorg file you can run sudo Xorg -configure

Comment: Please give me a step by step instruction

Comment: And if you had a tutorial on how to install the proprietary drivers for Nvidia GTX 750 Ti, I would be happy. I dont have any "Additonal Drivers" so.. And I've tried everything. "nvidia-current": black screen. And of some reason you cant use "nvidia-detect" on Ubuntu :/

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/189364/258912

Answer (score -1):

I recently had this issue. What solved it was to simply update my Ubuntu.

1. Run 'Software Updater'
2. Restart Computer when prompted