# How can I change my resolution to 1280x1024

Tags: nvidia, resolution

How can I change my resolution to 1280x1024? I used the info from this link

[How set my monitor resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189246/how-set-my-monitor-resolution)

but it didn't work. This is what appears

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4INP.jpg

How can I fix this?
I'm using a nVidia GTX 660 GPU with the recommended driver.

Comment: Go to a terminal window and type in "xrandr"

Comment: I did that's what I got http://imgur.com/N01Gup4 . What now?

Comment: Have you tried `nvidia-settings`?

Comment: I tried but the 1280x1024 resolution is not there.