# Need help in changing & saving screen resolution permanently in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, display-resolution, amd-graphics

I have Lenovo Y40-90 laptop, and have Ubuntu 14.04 with integrated Intel graphics card and AMD Raden R9 M275 graphics card. I have also installed AMD Catalyst Center to switch between Intel and Radeon. I followed this answer: [How set my monitor resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189246/how-set-my-monitor-resolution/189364#189364) to set the resolution to 1600x900 (which was not in the original list of the resolutions).

I am able to set the resolution everytime, but after every reboot, or while playing a game (DOTA2, here), the screen flickers and it goes back to the highest 1920x1080. Also, I get a very tall error dialog box which is this:

[image]

I shall be really grateful if somebody could help me in setting the 1600x900 resolution permanently.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at here
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution
you may be able to find a solution. Good luck!

Comment: I am not able to do so. I follow the steps and the resolution reverts back to the same resolution along with the error message that I attached.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I couldn't get my monitor resolution to stick on reboot. I was using Lubuntu 14.04 at the time but it should work for lightdm on Ubuntu as well.

1) Install Arandr from Software Center or Synaptic.

2) Open it and configure your monitors.

3) Save the .sh file, open it as root and make it executable.

4) Copy the .sh file to /usr/share/

5) Open a terminal and type gksuo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

6) Comment out all lines that start with autologin

7) Edit and/or add the following lines:

greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter

user-session=ubuntu

display-setup-script=usr/share/filename.sh (replace "filename" with .sh file from step 3)

session-setup-script=usr/share/filename.sh (replace "filename" with .sh file from step 3)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Clint. I don't have a "lightdm.conf" file in /etc/lightdm/. There's only one file there by the name of "users.conf".

Comment: You should just be able to create a new text file with that name and save it with just those four lines.

Comment: Oh, OK. Thanks. Also, were you getting the same kind of error (along with the long error dialog box, as I screencapped)? I will try your points in the meantime.

Comment: No, I wasn't getting any error message.