# Can't change display resolution : nVidia GT610

Tags: nvidia, windows-7, 16.04, display-resolution

I was using Win7. But on Ubuntu 16.04 I get bad performance in every single game, no matter how old it is. So I thought I could add a lower custom resolution to improve the performance. Tried everything but nothing worked, xrandr throws errors and I can't seem to find anything else on the matter.
I'm using nVidia Geforce GT610 2GB with the latest driver "367.18" and 16:10 ratio. I'd love to add resolutions like 960x600 or 800x500, which worked on Win7.

Answer (score 0):

According to Nvidia, the latest driver for your card is:

Version:      **361.45**
Release Date: Tue May 24, 2016

GeForce 600 Series
GeForce GTX 690, GeForce GTX 680, GeForce GTX 670, GeForce GTX 660 Ti, GeForce GTX 660, GeForce GTX 650 Ti BOOST, GeForce GTX 650 Ti, GeForce GTX 650, GeForce GTX 645, GeForce GT 645, GeForce GT 640, GeForce GT 630, GeForce GT 620, **GeForce GT 610**, GeForce 605

You can add custom resolutions using the instructions offered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189246/how-set-my-monitor-resolution).

**NOTE** that you have to know the exact refresh rate your monitor supports for each and every resolution you want to add before you start this process.

Comment: Well, I can't update to 361.45, the closest one that's listed on updates is 361.42. And I can't install .45 that I downloaded from the Nvidia site. Still this seem irrelevant, because I need to add custom resolution.

Comment: It's not exactly irrelevant because in the question I read version "367.18" which does not exist for your card.  It was my guess that you were using an incorrect driver thus having the problems you describe.

Comment: I mean, I tried to do this with many drivers. It's always the same problem. Xrandr just doesn't work for me and I can't find anything else like an app or something.

Comment: I have edited my answer so that you can see if adding the resolutions you want the way described, solves your issue.  If it does though, you have to create a script that issues those commands and add it at the end of your **/etc/rc.local** file so that the system can set those resolutions on every system startup.