# HDMI output not filling monitor

Tags: display-resolution, display-manager

I've installed 16.04 on a brand new Lenovo P50 but when I connect my external monitor up, the desktop is displayed on screen but does not fill the monitor. The res is currently set to 1920x1200 but there's about 3 inches of black on each side of the screen.

Comment: check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/189246/how-set-my-monitor-resolution

Comment: The monitor supports 2560x1440 but when I add that mode to the device, the screen goes black and doesn't come back