# How can I set my refresh rate? badmatch error

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I have an external monitor connected to my laptop. It's currently set to 1920x1080p@60Hz. I want it set to 1920x1080p@75Hz. I've used this refresh rate in Windows 8.1 for over a year without problems. The monitor can be connected via DisplayPort or HDMI.

Kubuntu 17.10
Nvidia gtx 960m
Nvidia driver version: 384.98

### Update 2018/09/26:

Still not working. I even did a fresh install.

Kubuntu 18.04
Nvidia driver 390.48

## Things I have already tried

Format:

page where I found the instructions

command
result

[Changing refresh rate for specific monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861416/changing-refresh-rate-for-specific-monitor)

```
xrandr --output DP-3 --rate 75
```

Nothing happens.

```
xrandr --output DP-3 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 75
```

"no input/signal detected"

```
xrandr --output HDMI0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 75
```

Screen shakes/vibrates up and down.

[How set my monitor resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189246/how-set-my-monitor-resolution)

```
cvt 1920 1080 75

# 1920x1080 74.91 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 84.64 kHz; pclk: 220.75 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_75.00"  220.75  1920 2064 2264 2608  1080 1083 1088 1130 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --query | grep connected

HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
eDP-1-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm

xrandr --addmode DP-3 "1920x1080_75.00"

X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  50
  Current serial number in output stream:  51
```

https://askubuntu.com/a/380817/544685

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

No section named 'monitor'

https://askubuntu.com/a/727897/544685

```
gtf 1920 1080 75

# 1920x1080 @ 75.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 84.60 kHz; pclk: 220.64 MHz
  Modeline "1920x1080_75.00"  220.64  1920 2056 2264 2608  1080 1081 1084 1128  -HSync +Vsync

xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_75.00"  220.64  1920 2056 2264 2608  1080 1081 1084 1128  -HSync +Vsync

X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  50
  Current serial number in output stream:  50

cvt -r 1920 1080 75

ERROR: Multiple of 60Hz refresh rate required for  reduced blanking.
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851704/xrandr-errors-badname-named-color-or-font-does-not-exist#3414850

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080-ok"  220.64  1920 2056 2264 2608  1080 1081 1084 1128  -HSync +Vsync
```

Works (I think).

```
xrandr --addmode DP-3 "1920x1080-ok"
                              
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)                                                 
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)                                                                      
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)                                                             
  Serial number of failed request:  50                                                                              
  Current serial number in output stream:  51

xrandr --addmode DP-3 1920x1080-ok

X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)                                                                      
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)                                                             
  Serial number of failed request:  50                                                                              
  Current serial number in output stream:  51
```

Comment: I would pay so much money to get this working on my machine. I have Intel integrated graphics and I can't get my monitors to output at 3440x1440@75hz. One WAS working at that rate but just defaulted back to 29.9. It's infuriating.