# Change monitor default framerate

Tags: display, monitor, xrandr

My principal monitor defaults to 75Hz, but for some reason does not display anything when the frame rate is 75Hz on any of my devices (and OS). It does however work when changing to 60Hz.

I managed to lower the rate with Xrandr: `xrandr --output DP-1 --rate 59.95 --mode 2560x1440`.

The problem is that whenever I unplug the monitor, restart my computer or when it goes to screen saving, the frame rate is reset to its default (75Hz), not displaying anything.

**Is there a way of changing its default rate?**

I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861416/changing-refresh-rate-for-specific-monitor) thread, but for some reason I do not have a `~/.config/monitors.xml` file.

Here is the output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     74.60 +  59.95* 
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I assume the 'plus' sign is the default? Though I couldn't find a way of changing this in xrandr's manual.

Answer (score 0):

The 'plus' and 'asterisk' refer to 'preferred' and 'current', respectively. You can look at more detail by adding `--verbose` to `xrandr`.

To make the rate change permanently you could try to make a script that sets it every time you boot, as described [here](https://www.tecmint.com/set-display-screen-resolution-in-ubuntu/) to an external monitor, just changing the actual script shown there to the one you already have.