# Dual screen set up shows stylus position off set

Tags: multiple-monitors, touchscreen, stylus

**[Link to video for clarification](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1840vhK3q5TO1rr8gE9P7QVhzSW23THQ2/view?usp=sharing)**

I have Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on a 2-in-1 laptop (EVE V, 12.3" screen) with a touchscreen. When I use the laptop in the simple, mono-screen configuration the stylus works just fine. But when I connect an external monitor (Samsung 24") and use both screens in a dual set-up, then I get an offset in the cursor/drawing of the cursor. And this happens only when I use the stylus, if I use my finger for drawing the cursor location gets detected/displayed accurately! I figured out that the offset is only along the y-axis (vertical), along the x-axis (horizontal) there is no offset. And the offset is not constant along the screen, but gradual, increasing linearly towards the top of the touch screen. So it's like the computer tries to make also my Samsung monitor a touch screen. How can I correct that? Furthermore, the problem exists only on my Ubuntu OS, on Windows there is no offset (I have a dual partiticion) **[Here is a link to a video for clarification](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1840vhK3q5TO1rr8gE9P7QVhzSW23THQ2/view?usp=sharing).** Tnx

Comment: my script for screen rotation is xinput set-prop 'ELAN0732:00 04F3:2536 Pen (0)' --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 && xinput map-to-output 11 eDP   ....   the map to output would be your first attempt. 11 is the pen, EDP is the monitor from xrandr output.the 11 here is the xinput id for the pen and might change on reboots

Comment: @pierrely Thanks! But your instructions are all greek to me, I have a minimal level of unix understanding. Can you give me step by step instructions on what to do/ what to check?

Comment: briefly... in a terminal type xrandr and determine the name of your main monitor lets call this A . then type xinput and see if you can see the id number (and name) of your pen lets call this number B . if you have those two then type xinput map-to-output B A   .

Comment: @pierrely thanks a lot! I found that a lot of other people suggest your solution. But I found an even simpler one - just select on log-in that I want to use Wayland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 other questions very similar to mine [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270156/how-to-map-wacom-correctly-to-monitor) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839161/limit-a-graphics-tablet-to-one-monitor). As one of the contributors [answered here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1308720/771488), on start up I could just select that I want to use Wayland instead of xorg and this solved the issue completely for me. With just 1 click!