# HDMI connection disappeared

Tags: 12.04, hdmi

I'm using a Toshiba laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 on an Intel graphics controller, connected to a Philips monitor through HDMI. One fine day, the *connection* (let alone the monitor) via HDMI simply disappeared. I actually had the very same issue before, which was resolved with an update (just like this guy's [How to detect and configure an output with xrandr?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186288/how-to-detect-and-configure-an-output-with-xrandr)). That day, I recorded the updates that I ran, but it doesn't seem like there are any graphics updates. It seems that this is a systemic issue, so I would like to resolve it once and for all.

Thanks a lot in advance! Let me know if you need more details.

I tried:

1. reboot
2. `sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get update`
3. reconnect

Output from xrandr:

```
$ xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+312 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1366x768       60.2*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected 1920x1080+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 476mm x 268mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       75.0     59.9  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        72.8     75.0     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1
```

Output from lspci:

```
$ lspci -v

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor 
Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device 0004
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```