# Theoretical screen resolution

Tags: resolution, screen

After my laptop's screen broke down, I sent the laptop back to have the screen replaced. Unfortunately, it seems that they replaced it with a lower resolution screen.

I have the faint hope that the screen's resolution is actually higher that what Ubuntu is able to display (although it seems unlikely).

Is there a way to know for sure the physical (or "theoretical") resolution of the screen?

**Edit:** I tried xrandr as suggested in the comments, here is the output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Does this mean there's definitely no way the screen could be actually higher res than 1366 x 768? (I was expecting 1600*900)

**Edit:** Not sure why my question was downvoted. Anyway, since it seems there is no easy way to know for sure the native resolution of the screen, I fetched a screwdriver, took the screen apart to get its reference, and looked it up. It was a 1366x768 indeed, as I feared.

Comment: `xrandr` is the tool for that :) Here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/186288/how-to-detect-and-configure-an-output-with-xrandr

Comment: It seems a 1366 x 768 screen --- it's the most common resolution for laptops now. Didn't you ask for a datasheet - guarantee document for the new screen? You should have the details there.

Comment: No, there is no details on the paper stuff they gave me. It should not be a 1366*768, I bought the laptop two and half years ago and the original screen was 1600*900

Comment: Seems like you need to contact the manufacturer and complain about it being replaced with the wrong screen.

Comment: Probably indeed. But my question is: is there a way to know for sure the native screen resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have solved your problem, I'll just give you tricky hint you can simply open a Terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type: `xwininfo` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> you should get a crossed pointer simply click on your desktop with it and it will display info in terminal window about your screen including its **geometry** for example `-geometry 1920x1080+0+0`. Also if you want more detailed info run `xdpyinfo` you'll get a lot of info you can retrieve different info with commands for example: `xdpyinfo | grep screen` or `xdpyinfo | grep resolution` or `xdpyinfo | grep dimensions` and so on... I hope that's plenty enough for you. Good luck.

P.S.

To add more resolutions try workouts in a comment link sent by **Rinzwind**