# How do I get other resolution option other than default one in full screen?

Tags: graphics, resolution, screen, monitor

I want to get my 1366x768 monitor to have other screen resolution 800x600 or 1240x768 in full screen.

What option do I have? Thanks.

Here what I did,

> shaharil@busuk:~$ xrandr
>   Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
>   VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>   LVDS-0 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
>      1366x768       60.0*+
>   HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>
> shaharil@busuk:~$ cvt 800 600 60
>    # 800x600 59.86 Hz (CVT 0.48M3) hsync: 37.35 kHz; pclk: 38.25 MHz
>   Modeline "800x600_60.00"   38.25  800 832 912 1024  600 603 607 624 -hsync +vsync
>
> shaharil@busuk:~$ xrandr
>   Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
>   VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>   LVDS-0 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
>      1366x768       60.0*+
>   HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>
> shaharil@busuk:~$ xrandr --newmode "800x600_60.00"   38.25  800 832 912 1024  600 603 607 624 -hsync +vsync
>
> shaharil@busuk:~$ xrandr --addmode LVDS-0 800x600_60.00
>   X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
>     Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
>     Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
>     Serial number of failed request:  27
>     Current serial number in output stream:  28

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish before you mark this as duplicate, please clarify that I want to stress out that this problem is the other way around. I already got my native resolution that is 1366x768 as default as the only option I have, what I want is other option than native, that is 800x600 or 1024x768 in full screen which I don't have option to choose. Thanks.

Comment: the duplicate doesn't state on **native** resolution exactly, you can set any resolution you desire with that workaround :-)

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish Thanks for pointing that out, but I got error, shaharil@busuk:~$ xrandr --addmode LVDS-0 800x600_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  27
  Current serial number in output stream:  28

Comment: you mean you were adding this? e.g. `xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync`

Comment: it should look exactly like in tutorial even if occasionally hit `space` but you should know that it's a very sensitive case :-)

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish I'm passing that step, this error occur when I try to add the new created resolution, xrandr **--addmode** LVDS-0 800x600_60.00

Comment: can you please show full line you're trying to add

Comment: there are hints yet in a question if something not working like this http://askubuntu.com/questions/186288/how-to-detect-and-configure-an-output-with-xrandr or this http://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish I edit my question.

Comment: it worked with VGA, I have no clue maybe the cause of your connector LVDS, there still other way outs as I mentioned in my previous comment links.

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish Thank you very much, I guess so. In the mean time, I will try the other way outs, thanks.

Comment: Hope you'll work it out :-) in these links basically all the information you need to configure screen resolution. p.s. you can also see the synapsis in terminal `xrandr --help`