# XRandr possible configurations Ubuntu MATE 16.04

Tags: display, laptop, display-resolution, xrandr

I was checking out XRandr and I ran it rogue and it showed this in one of the lines :

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
```

Does this mean I can configure it to a maximum of maximum 32767 x 32767 pixels ?

It can use 1080 in HDMI but will it be possible in the laptop monitor ?

I managed to add a Virtual display

This is GTF output :

gtf 1920 1080 60 -x

```
# 1920x1080 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 67.08 kHz; pclk: 172.80 MHz
  Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync
```

This what I get when adding the mode to the laptop screen

```
xrandr --addmode LVDS1 1920x1080_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  34
  Current serial number in output stream:  35
```

This is my XRANDR output now

```
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      60.00*+  40.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1920x1080_60.00 (0x100) 172.800MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2040 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.08KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1081 end 1084 total 1118           clock  60.00Hz
  1440x1080_60.00 (0x101) 129.870MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1536 end 1688 total 1936 skew    0 clock  67.08KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1081 end 1084 total 1118           clock  60.00Hz
```

Comment: Hello again :) I found the same maximum in multiple different places on the 'net, for example: http://superuser.com/questions/428159/forcing-monitor-resolution-in-virtualbox-vm-on-linux-guest just FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum resolution that `xrandr` shows is that of the maximum virtual screen size.

The closest information I can find to help you with your question is:

https://pkg-xorg.alioth.debian.org/howto/use-xrandr.html#_placing_outputs_in_a_virtual_screen

Snipet:

```
Let’s have a look at the maximal virtual screen size, we see 4096x4096 in this example:

$ xrandr|head -1
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 800, maximum 4096 x 4096

With DRI and without KMS, that might be needed. Indeed, drivers will often create a default virtual screen with small dimensions, for instance 1600x1200, to reduce memory consumption.

If you plan to use multiple outputs displaying different zones, you should configure your xorg.conf by adding a Virtual line to the Display subsection in the Screen section.

Section "Screen"
  …
  SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Virtual 3000 2000
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Also see https://askubuntu.com/a/186616/231142

Hope this helps!