# 18.04 LTS + Intel HD 3000 Graphic : HDMI Not Working

Tags: hdmi, intel

I am new to Ubuntu and trying to make my newly installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my Dell XT2 laptop to work with 2 monitors. 1 monitor is connected via the laptop HDMI (Intel HD 3000 Graphic Chipset) and another via a USB 3.0 DVI adaptor using a DisplayLink driver. Initially, the HDMI works fine on the first attempt. So I had that working on 1 additional monitor. Next I installed the DisplayLink driver and once completed, I restarted the laptop. Now I cannot get the HDMI to work, ie. monitor keep saying no signal. The USB DVI adaptor seems to be working fine. So my problem is that I cannot get both HDMI and USB DVI display to work simultaneously. Can anyone help me please?

FYI, I have tried the same setup on another machine running Radeon Graphic card and that seems to work fine with both HDMI and USB DVI adaptor. So I am wondering if its a driver issue with the Intel HD 3000 Graphic. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried using `xrandr`? try `xrandr --auto`, it should detect both monitors

Comment: This [other post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186288/how-to-detect-and-configure-an-output-with-xrandr) may be of assistance

Comment: I have tried typing `xrandr --auto` in the console but there is no output and nothing changes. It seems that if I started the laptop with the HDMI disconnected, it will boot with the main monitor and 2nd monitor (via USB adapter). Once everything is started, I will connect the HDMI lead and the 3rd monitor will work. What else could be preventing the HDMI monitor to work on start-up?