# For Nomachine installed on a server, how do I increase the resolution?

Tags: display-resolution, remote-desktop, nomachine

The resolution is stuck at roughly 1000x700. Neither display settings nor xrandr + cvt let me adjust the available display sizes. How do I increase the resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Edit/create `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` to contain the following:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier "MyScreen"
    Subsection "Display"
        Virtual 1920 1080
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

(In the above case for a resolution of 1920x1080)
Credit: [How to detect and configure an output with xrandr?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186288/how-to-detect-and-configure-an-output-with-xrandr)