Unable to choose optimal display resolution after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04
Question: How can I get the optimal resolution (1920x1200) in my system?
Upon upgrading my desktop from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, my display quality dropped. I am unable to choose the optimal resolution for my monitor HP E24i G4 in Settings/Displays (Optimal resolution: 1920 x 1200 @ 60Hz).
I have read multiple threads where they suggest changing from Wayland to Xorg, and also manually adding the resolution to xrandr. Neither of them worked.
Below you can find my system's information.
# inxi -Gx


c2:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 41) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
DeviceName: ASPEED Video AST2500
Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc ASPEED Graphics Family
Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 149, IOMMU group 2
Memory at b6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at b7000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
I/O ports at f000 [size=128]
Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/2 Maskable- 64bit+
Kernel driver in use: ast
Kernel modules: ast

xrandr


Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 1920 x 2048
VGA-1 connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
1920x1080     60.00
1600x1200     60.00
1680x1050     59.95*
1600x900      60.00
1280x1024     60.02
1440x900      59.89
1280x800      59.81
1024x768      60.00
800x600       60.32
640x480       59.94
1920x1200_60.00  59.88

Also, under Settings, I see this:
Graphics: lvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7, 256 bits)
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Probably this will help https://askubuntu.com/questions/186288/how-to-detect-and-configure-an-output-with-xrandr

I tried what's said in the mentioned answer but I am still unable to choose the optimal resolution.
