# Display resolution

Tags: resolution, display

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my very very old notebook (for learning purposes). The installation was successful, but unfortunately I can not change my display resolution. It stucks at 800x600. This makes it very hard to work. My Notebook is a Fujitsu Siemens ESPRIMO Mobile V5535. I used Google, but I am a beginner in Ubuntu/Linux and did not understand anything. I even do not know the commands for the terminal in Ubuntu , so thats why I wrote my problem here. Hope I get some help ! Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did u try?

type display in search box
[image]

try to change resolution
[image]

Comment: Hello, the problem is that I can not change the resolution. It just stuck at this named resolution. I do have a feeling that my notebook does not recognize my onboard graphic card..

Comment: can u follow this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/19954/how-to-set-the-monitor-to-its-native-resolution-which-is-not-listed-in-the-resol

Comment: follow steps by Nikhil

Comment: Hello, nothing helped.

Comment: type xrandr in terminal and post output