# Low display resolution in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, resolution, display

Recently I installed Ubuntu 14.04, but its graphics/display resolution is too low. I am getting only 2 options in my Appearance setting, i.e. 1024x786 (4:3) and 800x600, with Unknown Display option. How can I fix this issue and get a better display resolution?

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 10)
```

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci | grep VGA` to your question.

Comment: Try this [How to set the monitor to its native resolution which is not listed in the resolutions list?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19954/how-to-set-the-monitor-to-its-native-resolution-which-is-not-listed-in-the-resol)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the proprietary driver for your graphics card?  This will you give you more options than the open source driver.