# Change Dekstop Resolution to 1920 x 1080

Tags: nvidia, resolution, desktop-environments

im using GTX 650

already install NVIDIA Driver Version 346.47

the biggest resolution only 1360x768

im already try auto, but not help

in win 8.1 can max to 1920x1080

how to change the resolution to 1920 x 1080?

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1360 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 connected primary 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0 +
   1360x768       60.0*    59.8  
   1152x864       60.0  
   800x600        72.2     60.3     56.2  
   680x384        60.0     59.8  
   640x480        59.9  
   512x384        60.0  
   400x300        72.2  
   320x240        60.1  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)


01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce GTX 650] [10de:0fc6] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. Device [19da:1288]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info

```
Number of GPUs: 1

GPU #0:
  Name      : GeForce GTX 650
  UUID      : GPU-53e44d51-d68e-40ec-916c-94b15d2bd2d0
  PCI BusID : PCI:1:0:0

  Number of Display Devices: 1

  Display Device 0 (CRT-0):
      No EDID information available.
```

this is how im install driver

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa -y
$ sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
reboot
```

Comment: What monitor do you have? I have similar results with a monitor that only supports resolutions up to 1360x768...

Comment: please add the outputs: `xrandr` and `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA` to your question.

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish updated

Comment: @ElderGeek im using Sony Bravia TV, in win 8.1 its can max up to 1920 x 1080

Comment: are you using proprietary drivery or manually installed? you can also include info from `nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info` Did you configure `X` after driver been installed if so.

Comment: im use this guide http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: did you do everything according to that tutorial? including `nvidia-xconfig` command.

Answer (score 0):

A TV is a bad choice for a monitor as most TVs don't provide correct resolution frequencies in hardware.

On Windows, this is fixed by hard-coding the resolutions into the drivers, but on Ubuntu, you need to [fix this yourself manually](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19954/how-to-set-the-monitor-to-its-native-resolution-which-is-not-listed-in-the-resol) or update the TV's firmware... (and complain when the firmware doesn't fix it and wait...)