# Blurry or messed up fonts after forced screen resize

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, amd-graphics

I have an AOC e2727she monitor that I wanted to use with my Dell Inspiron laptop running Ubuntu 16.04.  I plug it into my laptop using an HDMI to HDMI cable.  When I plug it in, thought,the highest resolution available is 1024x768 at 60.00 Hz.  I followed the directions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19954/how-to-set-the-monitor-to-its-native-resolution-which-is-not-listed-in-the-resol?lq=1/) to create a custom modeline for my monitor.

One of the things I noticed here is that Ubuntu thinks that my HDMI port is a DisplayPort, but I don't know if that's important.

Another important thing is, I can connect to the monitor with my Windows 10 laptop, and I can correctly resize the screen to 1920x1080.

I ran `cvt` and got this

```
-[zephyr@mimir3]-[~ 130] - 09:30 AM
-> cvt 1920 1080 60
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

I then incorporated this into xrandr

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DisplayPort-0 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr --output DisplayPort-0 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
```

I looked over at my other screen and it seemed to have worked, but when I moved a browser window over to it, all of the text and icons got messed up and blurry.  I can't really read off of it.

I'm at kind of a loss at what to do next.

Graphics card:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus XTX [Radeon HD 8890M / R9 M275X/M375X] (rev 83)
```

EDIT:
Here is the output of `sudo lshw -c display; xrandr --verbose`

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Venus XTX [Radeon HD 8890M / R9 M275X/M375X]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 83
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:139 memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:de400000-de43ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:de440000-de45ffff
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x5b) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
    Identifier: 0x55
    Timestamp:  636663
    Subpixel:   horizontal rgb
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3 4 5
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0030e49b0400000000
        0019010495221378ea5755a458559e24
        0d505400000001010101010101010101
        0101010101012e3680a070381f403020
        350058c21000001a522b80a070381f40
        3020350058c21000001a000000fe0046
        37484832803135365746360a00000000
        000041319e001000000a010a2020001d
    scaling mode: Full 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
  1920x1080 (0x5b) 138.700MHz +HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.68KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  60.02Hz
  1920x1080 (0x5c) 110.900MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  53.32KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  47.99Hz
  1680x1050 (0x5d) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
  1400x1050 (0x5e) 121.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1488 end 1632 total 1864 skew    0 clock  65.32KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1057 total 1089           clock  59.98Hz
  1280x1024 (0x5f) 109.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1368 end 1496 total 1712 skew    0 clock  63.67KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1027 end 1034 total 1063           clock  59.89Hz
  1440x900 (0x60) 106.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1528 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock  59.89Hz
  1280x960 (0x61) 101.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1360 end 1488 total 1696 skew    0 clock  59.70KHz
        v: height  960 start  963 end  967 total  996           clock  59.94Hz
  1280x854 (0x62) 89.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock  53.12KHz
        v: height  854 start  857 end  867 total  887           clock  59.89Hz
  1280x800 (0x63) 83.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock  49.70KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  831           clock  59.81Hz
  1280x720 (0x64) 74.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1472 total 1664 skew    0 clock  44.77KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  748           clock  59.86Hz
  1152x768 (0x65) 71.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1328 total 1504 skew    0 clock  47.71KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.78Hz
  1024x768 (0x66) 63.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1176 total 1328 skew    0 clock  47.82KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  775 total  798           clock  59.92Hz
  800x600 (0x67) 38.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  832 end  912 total 1024 skew    0 clock  37.35KHz
        v: height  600 start  603 end  607 total  624           clock  59.86Hz
  848x480 (0x68) 31.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   848 start  872 end  952 total 1056 skew    0 clock  29.83KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  493 total  500           clock  59.66Hz
  720x480 (0x69) 26.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  744 end  808 total  896 skew    0 clock  29.85KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  493 total  500           clock  59.71Hz
  640x480 (0x6a) 23.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  29.69KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  487 total  500           clock  59.38Hz
DisplayPort-0 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x56
    Timestamp:  636663
    Subpixel:   horizontal rgb
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3 4 5
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    output_csc: bypass 
        supported: bypass, tvrgb, ycbcr601, ycbcr709
    audio: auto 
        supported: off, on, auto
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    dither: off 
        supported: off, on
    underscan vborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: off, on, auto
    coherent: 1 
        range: (0, 1)
  1024x768 (0x4c1) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x4c2) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x4d2) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  848x480 (0x4d3) 33.750MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   848 start  864 end  976 total 1088 skew    0 clock  31.02KHz
        v: height  480 start  486 end  494 total  517           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x4c7) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x57
    Timestamp:  636663
    Subpixel:   horizontal rgb
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3 4 5
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    output_csc: bypass 
        supported: bypass, tvrgb, ycbcr601, ycbcr709
    audio: auto 
        supported: off, on, auto
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    dither: off 
        supported: off, on
    underscan vborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: off, on, auto
    coherent: 1 
        range: (0, 1)
DisplayPort-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x58
    Timestamp:  636663
    Subpixel:   horizontal rgb
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3 4 5
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    output_csc: bypass 
        supported: bypass, tvrgb, ycbcr601, ycbcr709
    audio: auto 
        supported: off, on, auto
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    dither: off 
        supported: off, on
    underscan vborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: off, on, auto
    coherent: 1 
        range: (0, 1)
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x59
    Timestamp:  636663
    Subpixel:   no subpixels
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3 4 5
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    output_csc: bypass 
        supported: bypass, tvrgb, ycbcr601, ycbcr709
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    load detection: 1 
        range: (0, 1)
```

EDIT:
I took a DVI cable that I was using with my main computer, and plugged it into a DVI to Mini Displayport adapter, and plugged that into my Dell.  This did manage to work.  Ubuntu came up with the display automatically and it was the correct name, unlike previously with the HDMI adapter.  Maybe something is wrong with the HDMI port on the monitor?  I won't mark this as answered as it doesn't explain what is happening with regards to the HDMI port.

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and add the output of `sudo lshw -c display; xrandr --verbose` ?

Comment: @Sneetsher question updated

Comment: The graphic card didn't receive `EDID` data on `DisplayPort-0`, Either: you are using a plug adapter, bad cable, bad contact,  or even the screen doesn't send it . Could you [edit] the question and add info what's the brand/model of monitor? how is it connected, is it HDMI-HDMI cable? (shorter the better)

Comment: @Sneetsher as I mentioned at the beginning of the question, the monitor is an AOC e2727she.  Also note my edit about connecting with Windows.