# How to get 1280x1024 with a BenQ T905?

Tags: nvidia, resolution, monitor

**Problem:**
Nvidia X-server settings offers me 1152x864 and 1360x768, but not the value 1280x1024 in-between that I need.
**How can I get the proper resolution (1280x1024) on Nvidia ION with Ubuntu 11.04?**

**Background:**
I've asked this question [before](https://askubuntu.com/q/19457/5786), but using a different computer. Now, I'm on a new computer (=new GPU) and the troubles have reappeared. It's evident by now that the root problem is that my monitor is not delivering proper EDID information to the computer, but I do not want to buy a new monitor, so I'm trying to find a software solution to make Ubuntu send the correct output. I had a working [solution](https://askubuntu.com/q/26682/5786) on 10.04 but editing the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file in section "Monitor" doesn't seem to work now, though it did back on 9.04.
Also, fiddling with 'xrandr' [used to work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19954/how-to-set-the-monitor-to-its-native-resolution-which-is-not-listed-in-the-resolu/19956#19956) (although badly and without acceleration, but doesn't work at all on this version, and [Oli mentions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26682/how-can-i-set-my-resolution-to-1280x1024-on-an-acer-aspire-revo-3700/26690#26690) that 'xrandr' doesn't work with the closed Nvidia drivers anyway so that's not where I should be looking.

**Data:**

- My monitor is an LCD panel: vendor is BenQ, model T905, with 1280x1024 resolution at 60Hz, connected via a normal VGA cable.
- In the control panel's "Additional Hardware", it says that the "Nvidia accelerated graphics driver [current version] (Recommended)" is "activated but not currently in use". There's a button to remove it, but no button to put it "in use".
- I've edited xorg.conf as described in an [earlier solution](https://superuser.com/questions/60290/cant-set-1280x1024-on-ubuntu-with-nvidia-geforce-8400-gs/63628#63628), but this doesn't seem to change anything even after a reboot:

  > Section "Monitor"
  >   Identifier "Monitor0"
  >   VendorName "BenQ"
  >   ModelName "T905"
  >   HorizSync 31.0 - 81.0
  >   VertRefresh 56.0 - 76.0
  >   EndSection
- `$ cvt 1280 1024 60` results in:

  > 1280x1024 59.89 Hz (CVT 1.31M4) hsync: 63.67 kHz; pclk: 109.00 MHz Modeline "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
- The output of `xrandr -q` contains the error:

  > xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I can fix it, but I have to **re-do these steps after every reboot:**
*Can anyone edit in the steps to make this stick across reboots?*

- run `sudo nvidia-xconfig`
- reboot
- with sudo, edit the file "/etc/X11/xorg.conf" and replace the two lines ("HorizSync" and "VertRefresh") with the following:

> HorizSync 31.0 - 81.0
>   VertRefresh 56.0 - 76.0

- Restart
- Start "Nvidia X Server Settings" again
- Now the "Resolution" dropdown listbox contains *many* more entries, and 1280x1024 is among them. Select it and press button "Apply" then "OK".